# How to understand the result of integrating this `InterpolatingFunction`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I have this function

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Interpolation[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, x, InterpolationOrder -> 0], x];
```

that I plot along with its integral, which clearly has the wrong slope (the yellow curve should have 0 slope at x=1). Differentiating the integral (which seems to run correctly) doesn't yield the original function at all:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], Integrate[f[x], x], D[Integrate[f[x], x], x]}], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

I don't think the discontinuity of the integral is much of a deal, because the integral **is** continuous in the range where `InterpolatingFunction` doesn't warn about extrapolation.

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you aware that the integrand of $f$ is defined over $[1,2]$ and constant, as defined by a 0-order interpolation between two points? The blue curve is right over $[1,2]$, but the yellow one seems wrong. The green one seems coherent with the wrong yellow one. There is no discontinuities in $[1,2]$. The problem seems to be in the integration of $f$.

Comment: I am confused by the attempt to obtain an *indefinite* integral from an `InterpolatingFunction`. It mixes an inherently symbolic operation with an intrinsically numerical one. If you used a symbolic piecewise function with the same behavior as your interpolating function in the $[1,2]$ domain where the interpolation is defined (i.e. `Piecewise[{{2, x < 1}, {4, x >= 1}}]`), then everything seems to work. I don't know how the result from `Integrate` is generated, but I can't really blame it for being unpredictable: I wouldn't know what to do either, if faced with the same question :-)

Answer (score 2):

If "I think it should be considered a bug" is answer, then this is an answer.  Otherwise, it's just an explanation of what gets constructed by the OP's code.

The computed integral of `f` is equivalent to

```
zz = Interpolation[{{{1}, 0, 0, 1}, {{2}, 2, 4, 2}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

and has the same sort of erroneous interpolation, e.g., `zz[1]` returns `-1` instead of `0`.

```
yy = Head@Integrate[f[x], x];
yy === zz
(*  True  *)
```

The problem seems to be that the integral of `f[x]` is not promoted from an order `0` to an order `1` interpolation.  I believe that's a bug.  Normally `Integrate` raises the interpolation order by `1`.

However, the bugs aren't done yet.  I tried changing the `InterpolationOrder` of the OP's example to `1`, and it didn't fix everything. The integral was okay, but the derivative of the integral, which is quadratic, was wrong, that is, it seems to be cubic (or higher)!

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@{f[x], Integrate[f[x], x], D[Integrate[f[x], x], x]},
 {x, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `Integrate` does a ***symbolic*** antiderivative of an `InterpolatingFunction`. Since an `InterpolatingFunction` is a piecewise polynomial, this shouldn't be surprising.  Like with other results of `Integrate`, you perhaps should not rely on the constant of integration that might be added, but it seems always to start from zero at the initial end point of the interval.  `Integrate` constructs a new `InterpolatingFunction` by specifying function data at each grid point as follows:  If at $x_j$, we have given
$$f(x_j), f'(x_j), \dots, f^{(n)}(x_j)\,,$$
then in the antiderivative $F$ constructed by `Integrate` there will be
$$F(x_j), F'(x_j), \dots, F^{(n)}(x_j), F^{(n+1)}(x_j)\,.$$
It also (except in the OP's order `0` case) adds one to the interpolation order.
(One might wonder that since it adds two data points, i.e., the values of the next derivative at each end point of a subinterval, the order could go up by two in Hermite interpolation.  But since we're integrating polynomials, we know the degree only goes up by one.)

Derivatives of an `InterpolatingFunction` are computed in a very different way.  They are computed by `InterpolatingFunction` from the interpolation data for the original function `IF`.  All that happens in `D[IF[x], x]` or `IF'` is that an integer is incremented, an integer that indicates which derivative of the interpolating data to compute on a numeric input for `x`.  It seems that this algorithm doesn't compute the derivative correctly in the above example.  In fact, the derivatives appear to be the derivatives of a degree-5 polynomial, corresponding to the six data points seen in `zz`:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{1}, 0, 0, 1}, {{2}, 2, 4, 2}}, x]
```

See [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4) for information about the innards of interpolating functions.