# How to extract the domain of the definition of the interpolating function?

Tags: interpolation

When calling the interpolated function without specifying the value of the argument, Mathematica displays its domain of the interpolation. How to extract it?

Comment: If `if` is your interpolating function, then do `if["Domain"]`.

Comment: To those voting to close because it is a simple mistake easily found in the documentation, where do you find it?  [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html)

Comment: The question is answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4).