# How to replace the expression in nest?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, replacement, warning-messages

I need to calculate the following function with replacement in recurrence

```
f[x0_, y0_]:= (s1 + s2)/t1 /. {s1 -> 
NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0., 
   x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., y[0.] == y0, y'[0.] == 0.}, 
  y, {t, 0, t1}][t1], s2 -> NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0.,
    x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., y[0.] == y0, y'[0.] == 1.}, 
  y, {t, 0, t1}][t1]} /. {t1 -> Take[Reap[
    NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., 
      WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {Sow[t], "StopIntegration"}]}, 
     x, {t, 0., 100.}, 
     MaxStepSize -> 0.001]], {2, -1}][[1]][[1]][[1]]}
```

But I meets an error says "NDSolveValue: Endpoint t1 in {t, 0., t1} is not a real number".

The key expression is

```
NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0., 
 x[0.] == 1., x'[0.] == 0., y[0.] == 1., y'[0.] == 0.}, 
y, {t, 0, Re[t1]}][Re[t1]] /. {t1 -> Take[Reap[
    NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0.] == 1., x'[0.] == 0., 
      WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {Sow[t], "StopIntegration"}]}, 
     x, {t, 0., 100.}, 
     MaxStepSize -> 0.001]], {2, -1}][[1]][[1]][[1]]}
```

which comes the error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. The innermost equation has an analytical solution ($x(t)=\cos{t}$), for instance.

Comment: You are asking *Mathematica* to numerically solve for `s1` with a symbolic endpoint `t1` and then *afterwards* replacing `t1` with a calculated value. To avoid the warning, compute `t1` first.

Comment: @SimonWoods, because I construct a function with this expression, so I need it compute in one time.

Comment: @MarcoB, I construct a function which is similar to the expression. The simple example here is just to show you the error I meet, not the exactly expression I need.

Comment: When I execute your code, I get no error. Please include the code that causes the error.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I just edit the question, and it gets an error when put some exact variable into the function, like f[1., 1.].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `t1` replacement in the `s1,s2` substitution, grouping with parentheses:

```
ff[x0_, y0_] := s1 + s2 /. (
    {s1 :> 
       NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0., 
          x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., y[0.] == y0, y'[0.] == 0.}, 
         y, {t, 0, t1}][t1], 
      s2 :> NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, 
          y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0., x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., 
          y[0.] == y0, y'[0.] == 1.}, y, {t, 0, t1}][t1]} /. {t1 ->
       NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., 
         WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {"StopIntegration"}]}, 
        Indexed[x["Domain"], {1, -1}], {t, 0., 100.}, 
        MaxStepSize -> 0.001]}
    );

ff[-1, -3]

(*  -2.54137  *)
```

Alternative:

```
ff[x0_, y0_] := 
  Block[{t1 = 
     NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., 
       WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {"StopIntegration"}]}, 
      Indexed[x["Domain"], {1, -1}], {t, 0., 100.}, 
      MaxStepSize -> 0.001]},
   s1 + s2 /.
    {s1 :> 
      NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0., 
         x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., y[0.] == y0, y'[0.] == 0.}, 
        y, {t, 0, t1}][t1], 
     s2 :> NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, 
         y''[t] + x[t]^2 y[t] == 0., x[0.] == x0, x'[0.] == 0., 
         y[0.] == y0, y'[0.] == 1.}, y, {t, 0, t1}][t1]}
   ];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What's the function of the extra "Indexed[x["Domain"], {1, -1}]" in your expression?

Comment: And it doesn't calculate correctly when I change the definition of the function into ff[x0_, y0_] := (s1 + s2)/t1

Comment: @JieJiang Use `Block` instead of replacement: `f[x0_, y0_] := Block[{t1 = NDSolveValue[...]}, ...]`.  You can look up `Indexed`. It's a delayed version of `Part`. Or maybe you mean `x["Domain"]`, which gives the interval of the domain of an `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4 for more about `InterpolatingFunction`, which is what `NDSolve` computes.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. I have edit the question, and I try to use Block but don't know how to do it, can you show me your solution?

Comment: Thank you so much again!

Comment: @JieJiang You're welcome!