# Legendre–Fenchel transformation of discrete data

Tags: list-manipulation

Let us define the Legendre–Fenchel transformation of a function $f(s)$ as:
$$g(j)=\max_s (js - f(s))\; .$$
I have a list of data $\{ \{s_1 , f(s_1)\} , \{ s_2, f(s_2) \},\cdots \}$. I am looking for a way to do the transformation. Any idea?

Comment: Try `Max[data.{j, -1}]`, where `data` is your list of pairs.

Comment: (1) A question like this should have a set of sample inputs in copy-pastable format. (2) If you sort the values `f(s_i)/s_i` then it is straightforward to figure out, for given `j`, which of these is furthest.

Comment: Thank you so much you all. It works @J. M.'s ennui

Comment: @ Daniel Lichtblau I do have an input list but it contains 8000 pairs. I did not know how to insert it here.

Comment: Inserting 20 of the pairs, instead of all of them, would probably be enough. Or make up data: `data = Table[{s, Exp[s]}, {s, -1., 1., 1./16}]` or use a nonconvex function if that is what you are interested in. (Site tip: The SE reply operator @ should not have spaces in the name, even if they are displayed. Thus: @DanielLichtblau.)

Comment: @Michael-E2 Thank you so much for both comments. I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an extension of the Legendre-Fenchel transform from data to the interpolation of data. An important hypothesis in what follows is that the function data is (strictly) convex. The derivative must be strictly increasing or the `Interpolation` will be faulty.  The main advantage is the ability to compute the derivative of the LF transform easily.

```
solIF = NDSolveValue[{f''[s] == f[s] + Sin[4 f[s]], f[0] == 1, 
    f'[0] == 1}, f, {s, -2, 1}];
(* the function data *)
fcoords = First@solIF@"Coordinates";
fvals = solIF@"ValuesOnGrid";
data = Transpose[{fcoords, fvals}];
(* construction of the Legendre-Fenchel transform *)
lfcoords = solIF'@"ValuesOnGrid";
lfvals = fcoords*lfcoords - fvals;
lfIF = Interpolation[
   Transpose@{ArrayReshape[lfcoords, {Length@lfcoords, 1}],
     lfvals, fcoords}];
```

The function plot (and data in red):

```
ListLinePlot[solIF, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

> [image]

The LF transform, comparing both J.M.'s `Max[..]` method and the interpolating function:

```
Plot[{Max[data . {j, -1}], lfIF[j]},
 {j, First@lfcoords, Last@lfcoords},
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], AbsoluteThickness[2]}]
```

> [image]

The derivative (plotting the derivative of `Max[..]` takes ~13 sec. for me):

```
Plot[{D[Max[data . {j, -1}], j], lfIF'[j]} // Evaluate,
 {j, First@lfcoords, Last@lfcoords},
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], AbsoluteThickness[2]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: This can be considered as the best answer to my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I find out that solIF@"Coordinates" returns the coordinates? In other words how do I get the properties attached to something like solIF? What are the existing keywords? Thanks!

Comment: @chris I first learned about it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4). You can also find the properties/methods from `solIF@"Methods"`. (Several high-level data structures may be queried this way or through `solIF@"Properties"`.) There is a package [``InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html) that provides interfaces to some of the methods.

Comment: @Ferhat You're welcome. Thanks for the accept. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I knew about Properties but not Methods