# Call function defined in Mathematica from Matlab

Tags: interpolation, external-calls, matlab

Is it possible to call a defined function inside Mathematica like `InterpolationFunction[...]` from Matlab?

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow related [InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise/) and [What's inside InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4).

Comment: Well, I'd argue this is a MATLAB question?

Comment: @xzczd It  concerns the interaction between the platforms Mathematica and Matlab!

Comment: I think the question should at least be clarified. What do you mean by "transfer"?

Comment: Looking at the documentation of MATlink (http://matlink.org/documentation/) it seems unlikely to me to directly send an `InterpolationFunction` Mathematica object to matlab. But sending the data-array inside the `InterpolationFunction`  seems relatively simple.

Comment: Any reason MatLab's interpolation functions wont do the trick?

Comment: @N0va Helpful  idea, thanks!

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267607/77079) would be useful.

Comment: @BenIzd Very interesting, I have to elaborate. Thanks!