# Set the FunctionInterpolation step

Tags: interpolation

Is there a way to specify the grid spacing for interpolation?

For example I would like the values of **a** to change in step of 0.34. How can I write this step in the FunctionInterpolation?

`f = FunctionInterpolation[NIntegrate[-a*(x - 5)^2 - 3 Sqrt[y] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}], {a, 0, 3}]`

And what is default step Mathematica uses?

Comment: Not an answer but I always used Interpolation and made the list using Table.

Comment: is it impossible to do for FunctionInterpolation?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[-a*(x - 5)^2 - 3 Sqrt[y] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

You can specify the step size using the standard form for an iterator.

```
fi = FunctionInterpolation[f[a], {a, 0, 3, 0.34}]
```

[image]

However, the iterator stops at `2.72` and the upper portion of the interval `{0, 3}` then requires extrapolation.

```
fi[2.9]

(* bInterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {2.9} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. *)

(* -830.555 *)

Plot[{f[a], fi[a]}, {a, 0, 3},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed["Expressions", {.8, .65}]]
```

[image]

Comment: When I write this line `fi = FunctionInterpolation[f[a], {a, 0, 3, 0.34}]` Mathematica highlights step (this part **, 0.34**) in red, like a mistake in syntax.

Comment: Does the code execute as expected despite the red color? If not, what version are you running and on what OS?

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 12.0 on Windows 10. But surprisingly it executes correctly. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: I'm confused. If it executes correctly, what do you want to change?

Comment: It's just weird to see some red code.

Comment: Is there any way apply EvaluateMonitor to FunctionInterpolation to I can see changing?

Comment: To see the insides of InterpolatingFunction see [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/9362)