# Export NDSolve data

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, list-manipulation, interpolation

I have calculated a solution of a system of differential equations using `NDSolve` and generated a plot. How could I extract the data of the solutions? The input is as follows:

```
κ := 2; n := 1; m := 1 ; γ := 0.1 ;

NDSolve[
{Subscript[U, 2]''[t] + (n^2 + 5 m^2/Cos[m t]^2) Subscript[U, 2][t] == 0, 
 Subscript[F, 2]''[t] + (n^2 + 5 m^2/Cos[m t]^2) Subscript[F, 2][t] + 
     24 γ κ^3 m Sin[m t] Cos[m t]^2 Subscript[F, 8][t] ==
     0, 
Subscript[F, 8]''[t] + (n^2 + m^2) Subscript[F, 8][t] + 24 γ κ^3 m Sin[m t] Cos[m t]^2 Subscript[F, 2][t] == 0, 
Subscript[F, 2][0] == 0, Subscript[F, 2]'[0] == 1, Subscript[F, 8][0] == 0, Subscript[F, 8]'[0] == 1, Subscript[U, 2]'[0.] == 1, Subscript[U, 2][0] == 0}, {Subscript[U, 2], Subscript[F, 2], Subscript[F, 8]}, {t, 0, 0.4999 π}];

Plot[Evaluate[{Subscript[F, 2][t], Subscript[U, 2][t]} /. %], {t, 0, 0.4999 π}]
```

Comment: Have you seen `Table[]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3):

As noted by J. M. in the comments, the easiest way to do this is to create a `Table` of `x` and `t` values.  However, if you want to actually extract the data points calculated by Mathematica, the [`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html) package allows you to get this data out.  An example:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
soln = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -5 (1 + 1000 Exp[-100 t^2]) x[t], x[-5] == 0, x'[-5] == 1}, x, {t, -5, 5}]
xsoln = x /. First[First[soln]]
tvals = First[InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[xsoln]];
xvals = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[xsoln];
ListPlot[Transpose[{tvals, xvals}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note the differing spacing of the data points in the quickly-varying region, due to Mathematica's adaptive step-size algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the kind of interpolation produced by `NDSolve` for an ODE can depend on the `Method` and the setting of `InterpolationOrder`.  I will answer just for the OP's case, which is the usual case.  `NDSolve` stores more data than just the abscissae and ordinates. It also stores derivative values at each abcissa, up to the order of the ODE. I will show how to package this in a table of the form
$$\{ \,\{\,x_i,y_i,y_i',y_i'',\dots\,\},\dots\,\}$$

The easy way to do this is the following if `sol` is the solution to the OP's `NDSolve` command:

```
With[{f = Subscript[U, 2] /. First@sol},
 data = Table[{x, f[x], f'[x], f''[x]}, {x, First@f["Coordinates"]}]]

(*  {{0., 0., 1., -2.1684*10^-19}, {0.000107875, 0.000107875, 1., -0.00064725},...  *)
```

There are sometimes very slight round-off errors compared with the data stored in the solution.  The following extracts the data from the solution's `InterpolatingFunction` for `Subscript[U, 2]`.  Some description of the internal structure may be found here, [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4),
and some more can be found here,
[Interpolating data with a step](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step/98349#98349).  The usual `InterpolatingFunction` produced by `NDSolve` has the data stored in an argument of the form

```
{Developer`PackedArrayForm, idcs_, vals_}
```

where `vals` is a flattened array of the ordinates and derivative values.  The indices `idcs` indicate where to partition `vals` to recover the array.  Usually in a solution to an ODE these are equally spaced.  The code below assumes all this.  If it fails, then the solution at hand is not of the form I have been calling "usual."

```
solvals = 
  First@ Cases[
    Subscript[U, 2] /. First@sol,
    {Developer`PackedArrayForm, idcs_, vals_} :> 
     Partition[vals, Differences@idcs /. {n_Integer ..} :> n], 
    Infinity];
data = Transpose@ Join[Subscript[U, 2]["Coordinates"] /. First@sol, Transpose[solvals]]

(*  {{0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0.000107875, 0.000107875, 1., -0.00064725},...  *)
```