# Using NDSolve`StateData without processing it into rule

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerical-integration, numerics, memory

## Problem

I need to solve a differential equation system. Nothing fancy here so far with the issue of too less memory on my machine. The interpolation functions I get from `NDSolve` eat up my 16GB memory very fast and the machine starts to create large swap files then. This should be avoided. I almost fear this question will be closed as duplicate - but even with thorough reading I didn't find an answer to my specific questions below. Before you vote for close please continue with reading - I won't ask "How can I do this", my issue is a bit more complex as it involves both understanding the `` NDSolve`StateData `` (Question 1) and getting information from it *very fast* (Question 2).

## Ideas and Questions

Having a look at the [2D Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/complex-valued-21d-pde-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-numerical-method-for-ndsolve/27970#27970) or the [official MMA documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) seems promising as we are able to split `NDSolve` into parts of

- 1st) preparing with `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations ``,
- 2nd) iterating with `` NDSolve`Iterate ``,
- 3rd) processing with `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions ``.

This way only the `` NDSolve`StateData `` has to be kept in memory. A first early question that comes to my mind now:

---

*Question 1:* How does all this work? I read the linked documentation but am not able to fully understand it. Let us assume we have an explicit, one-step integration scheme of fourth order (like the well-known Runge-Kutta-4 approach). In university I learned it is only needed to keep information about the *latest* step $i$ in order to compute the $i+1$st step. Measuring the size of the underlying `` NDSolve`StateData `` object seems to prove this. It grows only with the first step (i.e. the first usage of `` NDSolve`Iterate ``) and then maintains a constant size.

I would naively assume it is now only possible to get information about the data values of the functions and first derivatives **for the $i+1$st step**. This is only partly true.

```
NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[stateData, "Forward"]
```

gives me the numerical values in the $i+1st$ step as expected but

```
NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[stateData]
```

gives me full `InterpolatingFunction` objects that I up to now have not considered possible because this would only be possible if all values in between would be stored as well. The constant `ByteCount` seems to say something different. So: How is MMA able to build `InterplatingFunctions` over the complete domain without storing all data for all done steps?

---

Let us now assume the differential equation system was built and iterated. To get results I now have the possibility to process the solutions (see 3rd step above) to get rules (either for a specific step or interpolation functions as mentioned in *Question 1*). I could for example repeatedly use

```
h[ti]/.NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[stateData, "Forward"]
```

to get the vector $\vec h$ for the latest step $t_i$. The replacement in each step is very time-consuming so I looked for alternatives in the linked Wolfram documentation. It seems it is possible to get the underlying raw solution very fast by means of

```
stateData@"SolutionData".
```

`Part[#,3]&` of it would be the sought after numerical list in my case. Unfortunately, `NDSolve` sorts the coefficients different (h1,h1',h10,h10',…) than I do (h1,h2,h3,…). This leads me to the

---

*Question 2:* Is there a fast way to get the function values (derivates not needed) correctly sorted from the `NDSolve`-Framework other than sorting it myself in each step? If the answer is yes: Is it faster than time and again using `ReplaceAll` as shown above?

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Update notice: I discovered that `MaxStepFraction` is applied locally in `` NDSolve`Iterate[] `` to the length of the interval being "iterated," not to the global interval specified in `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations[] ``.  Also added interpolation methods that do not copy/unpack the array of function values.]*

---

***(1)*** How does this all work?

Since "all" seems rather broad, I'll give my interpretation for ODEs, for which I am much more familiar with the interpolation schemes than for PDEs.  I suspect that the cumulative solution is stored in a private variable (which I failed to find) and not in state data structure returned by `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations ``.  The state stores only the data for the current step.  But it's clear the total memory use of *Mathematica* grows linearly with the number of steps `NDSolve` takes.  Furthermore, the growth rate is optimal for the solution being computed.  By optimal, I mean if the setting is `InterpolationOrder -> Automatic`, then the rate is.  For an ODE of order $n$, `NDSolve` stores by default the values
$$x_k,\ y_k,\ y'_k, \dots,\ y^{(n)}_k$$
plus step indices for the `` Developer`PackedArrayForm `` of the Hermite `InterpolatingFunction` of the solution (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108172/export-ndsolve-data/108197#108197) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4)).  That means that $n+3$ 64-bit numbers are stored for each step, and memory usage can be observed to grow at $8\,(n+3)$ bytes per step.

Note that the data is not stored if the `NDSolve` call is of the form

```
NDSolve[ode, {}, {x, x1, x2}]
```

This indeed saves memory and returns no output.  Presumably one uses this in conjunction with [`StepMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html) or [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) to construct other data.  I tried using `StepMonitor` to construct a table of just the function values, but I wasn't really able to beat `NDSolve`.

***(2)*** What is a fast way to get the function values?

The reason that `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[] `` is slower than `` NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[] `` is that `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[] `` restructures the stored data for the `InterpolatingFunction` that it creates, which entails copying the data.  `` NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[] `` simply copies the current values stored in `state`.

Here is a way to extract the values of the variables without knowing the structure of the solution data (from the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#71074027)):
This could be used to get function values at prescribed values of the independent variables without accumulating all the data.  It may be sufficient for some use-cases.

```
vars = {y, z};
t1 = 0; t2 = 20; dt = 1./8;
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y'[t] == z[t], z'[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0},
   {}, {t, t1, t2}, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1];   (* see usage note below *)
vpos = Position[
   NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"VariableData", "X"], 
   Alternatives @@ vars, 1];
data = Table[
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, tt];
   Extract[NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"SolutionData"["Forward"], "X"], vpos],
   {tt, t1, t2, dt}];
data // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(* False *)

ListLinePlot[Transpose@data, DataRange -> {t1, t2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One drawback is that `data` is not packed, no matter how long the table.  One could generate packed data as follows:

```
comp[tt_] := (NDSolve`Iterate[state, tt]; 
   Extract[NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"SolutionData"["Forward"], "X"], vpos]);
gendata = Compile[{t1, t2, dt},
   Table[comp[tt], {tt, t1, t2, dt}],
   {{comp[_], _Real, 1}}];
data = gendata[t1, t2, dt];
data // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(* True *)
```

The compiled function consists of a single `MainEvaluate` call to `comp[tt]`, so
the only benefit of compiling is that it generates a packed array for output.  For the test case `t1 = 0; t2 = 10000; dt = 1./16`, the compiled version took 10% longer but the packed `data` was 1/8 the size.

If interpolation is needed, one can avoid copying `data` by applying `InterpolatingPolynomial` to just the data values needed, which is relatively easy to do since the values are over a uniform `dt` grid.  For `data` as above (each row is a vector of values of different functions), the following will calculate the piecewise cubic interpolation at a real number `t` of the function with index `f` in the rows of `data`.  On the example above, it is also much faster than `Interpolation`, unless you want to do more than a few thousand individual interpolations.  Also note that if `data` is not a packed array, the pattern check `?MatrixQ` will slow down evaluation considerably.

```
Clear[interp];
interp[data_?MatrixQ, f_Integer, t1_Real, t2_Real, dt_Real, t_] := 
 With[{idx = Clip[Floor[(t - t1)/dt], {1, Length@data}]},
  InterpolatingPolynomial[
   Transpose@{t1 + Range[idx - 1, idx + 2] dt, data[[idx ;; idx + 3, f]]}, t]
  ]
```

On packed `data`, using a compiled function is much faster:

```
interpC = Compile[
  {{data, _Real, 2}, {f, _Integer}, {t1, _Real}, {t2, _Real}, {dt, _Real}, {t, _Real}},
  Module[{idx, vals, dd = {0., 0., 0., 0.}, ft},
   idx = Floor[(t - t1)/dt];
   If[idx < 1, idx = 1];
   If[idx > Length@data - 3, idx = Length@data - 3];
   dd = data[[idx ;; idx + 3, f]];           (* Newton divided differences *)
   Do[
    dd[[j ;; 4]] = Differences[dd[[j - 1 ;; 4]]]/((j - 1)*dt),
    {j, 2, 4}];
   ft = dd[[4]];                             (* interpolate *)
   Do[
    ft = dd[[j]] + (t - t1 - (idx + j - 2) dt) ft,
    {j, 3, 1, -1}];
   ft
   ],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
  ]
```

*`NDSolve` usage note:*
The default setting of `MaxStepFraction` is `1/10`.  When using `` NDSolve`Iterate[] ``, this is applied to the length of the interval being computed by `Iterate[]`, i.e., `dt` in the example above; it is not applied to the length of the interval `{t, t1, t2}` of the original call.  For a small `dt`, the default setting might lead to as many as ten times the steps as necessary.  Setting it to larger value will save time.  For the case `t1 = 0; t2 = 10000; dt = 1./16`, the setting `MaxStepFraction -> 1` takes 1/3 less time.

---

***Example:***
This is a second order equation, so it should use `8*(2 + 3) == 40` bytes per step (marginal rate).

```
Quit[]

(* new cell *)
times = Flatten@N@Outer[Times, 10^Range[-1, 5], {1, 2, 5}];
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   {y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0},
   y,  (* change to {} to see no growth in memory usage *)
   {x, 0, 1000000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> 1];
data = Table[NDSolve`Iterate[state, x1]; {x1, MemoryInUse[]}, {x1, times}];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Getting the bytes per step rates:

```
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
grid = y["Grid"] /. sol // Flatten;
steps = LengthWhile[grid, x \[Function] x <= #] & /@ times
(* steps at the end of each NDSolve`Iterate:
  {15, 26, 40, 55, 69, 95, 137, 216, 448, 829, 1587, 3856, 7627, 15157, 
   37771, 75450, 150832, 377150, 754497, 1509044, 3743165}
*)

Differences@data[[All, 2]] / Differences@steps // N
(* Bytes per step, for each iteration interval
  {61.0909, 6.28571, 44.8, 94.2857, 26.4615, 45.7143, 39.6962, 34.8276, 
   38.9921, 39.905, 38.8365, 39.1811, 39.0704, 39.0806, 39.0522, 
   39.0707, 39.081, 39.0805, 39.077, 39.0725}
*)
```

(Note that due to auxiliary code using and releasing memory, exact results rarely occur.)

One can reduce the per step memory usage by reducing the order of the system:

```
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   {y'[x] == z[x], z'[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0},
   y,  (* keep only data on  y, discard  z  data *)
   {x, 0, 1000000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> 1];
```

This has roughly a 32 byte per step marginal rate of memory usage (`8 * (1 + 3) == 32`).

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly the explanation I was hoping for. Many thanks. I just saw it (sorry for the huge delay) and accepted it as promised.

Answer (score 2):

**Personal remark:** I never answered my own question up to now and usually refrain from doing so for good reason as it looks like simple reputation increase. I therefore won't accept my own answer, maybe someone comes around with something more specific whose answer will be accepted then by me.

---

**Possible fast solution:**
Assume `sys` is a DES that was built by `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations ``. Let `h[x]` be the sought after coefficient vector with the dependent variables of the DES in it.

First find the structure that maps `NDSolve`'s internal data format to our coefficient vector by using

```
DESDataOrder[sourceList_, targetList_] := {Ordering@sourceList, Ordering@Ordering@targetList};
hOrder = DESDataOrder[NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[sys@"Variables", "DependentVariables"], Head /@ h[x]];
```

and save the variable `hOrder` somewhere. Let's compare two approaches now:

```
SetAttributes[{DESStep, DESStepData}, HoldFirst];
```

*First approach:*

```
DESStep[stateData_, t_] := (NDSolve`Iterate[stateData, t]; NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[stateData, "Forward"]);
```

*Second approach:*

```
DESStepData[stateData_, t_] := (NDSolve`Iterate[stateData, t]; NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[(stateData@"SolutionData")[[2]], "DependentVariables"][[hOrder[[1]]]][[hOrder[[2]]]]);
```

*Comparison:*

Note that DESStep builds replacement rules whereas DESStepData just sorts the underlying data from `NDSolve` in such a form that we can get the numerical coefficient vector directly. Due to the not needed replacement via rules the second approach is noticeably faster:

```
numerical = DESStepData[sys, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.000052, Null}*)
ruleBased = h[1.] /. DESStep[sys, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.04334, Null}*)
```

Caution: This approach heavily relies on knowledge about the underlying data structure. This can (but hopefully won't) be changed by WRI.

Comment: Note that it's not the replacement rules but the construction of the `InterpolatingFunction` that causes `DESStep` to be slower (see my answer).