# Taking Part of an InterpolatingFunction

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation

I want a function to extract part of a one-dimensional [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html), similar to how [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html) works on lists.  Based on the code in [this question by polyglot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction), I put together the following function:

```
InterpolatingFunctionTake[if_InterpolatingFunction, {xmin_?NumericQ, xmax_?NumericQ}] :=
Interpolation[Join[
  {{xmin, if[xmin]}},
  Select[Transpose[{if["Coordinates"][[1]], if["ValuesOnGrid"]}], xmin < #[[1]] < xmax &],
  {{xmax, if[xmax]}}
]];
```

It generally works OK, but has two problems that I'd like to fix.

**Problem 1 - It can be slow**

When the `InterpolatingFunction` is big, it can take too long to run.  For example,

```
if = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t - 2]), n[0] == 0.1}, n, {t, 0, 20000}, MaxSteps -> ∞][[1]];

InterpolatingFunctionTake[if, {0.5, 1.5}]
```

takes almost 1 second for the `InterpolatingFunctionTake`.

*Can this be sped up?*

**Problem 2 - It fails on discontinuous functions**

Suppose there's a discontinuity in the function due to an impulse, modeled with a [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) in 
[`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).  For example,

```
if = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == 1, n[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], n[t] -> 0]}, n, {t, 0, 2}][[1]];

InterpolatingFunctionTake[if, {0.5, 1.5}]
```

gives the error "[`Interpolation::inddp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Interpolation/inddp): The point 1. in dimension 1 is duplicated."  Simply deleting one of the duplicate points is no good because it completely messes up the interpolation.

This very issue was explored in depth in [this answer by Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98349/6358).  His solution involves manually building up a new `InterpolatingFunction` based on a list of {x,y,y'} triplets.  It seems that once we're already that deep into the innards of the new `InterpolatingFunction`, we might as well work directly on the parts of the original `InterpolatingFunction` without making a list of {x,y,y'} triplets (particularly since there doesn't seem to be anything like `if["DerivativesOnGrid"]` to get the y' values out easily).

*Is there a good way to directly alter the internals of the `InterpolatingFunction`?*  (This seems slightly dangerous, but maybe the only way to achieve this?)

Comment: `if["DerivativesOnGrid"]` would be equivalent to `if'["ValuesOnGrid"]`.

Comment: There are many kinds of `InterpolatingFunction`.  Do you only want to deal with the kind that has the ``Developer`PackedArrayForm`` kind of interpolation data?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm only interested slicing up the 1D `InterpolatingFunctions` that `NDSolve` returns when solving time-dependent differential equations.

Comment: In fact for me (V11.1.1), your example has `if["InterpolationMethod"]` --> `"Local Taylor series"`, and it is not of the `PackedArrayForm` you show.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good catch - the first example's `InterpolationMethod` is "Local Taylor series" (and has no PackedArray in `if[[4]]`) and the second example's `InterpolationMethod` is "Hermite".  So attempting `InterpolatingFunction` surgery might be too risky ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This handles the `"Local Taylor series"`, `"Chebyshev"` and both the packed and unpacked `"Hermite"` interpolation method.  One thing I would recommend, and implemented below, is not to worry about cutting off the interpolation exactly at `tmin` or `tmax`.  Rather, take the smallest interval containing `tmin` and `tmax` with endpoints on the interpolation grid.  Actually the code below might include one more grid point at each end than is necessary.  This adds very little overhead.  On the other hand, dealing with dividing a subinterval with these methods might be a much bigger pain than it's worth.  In any case, the function in the "Code dump" below preserves these (more accurate!) interpolation methods.  It seems a shame to throw away the extra accuracy.  One might do it if speed is more important than accuracy.

OP's first example:

```
if1 = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t - 2]), n[0] == 0.1}, 
     n, {t, 0, 20000}, MaxSteps -> ∞][[1]];
if1["InterpolationMethod"]
(*  "Local Taylor series"  *)

ifTake[if1, {0.5, 1.5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.028446, InterpolatingFunction[{{0.478428, 1.53819}}, <>]}  *)

ifTake[if1, {1000.5, 1010.5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.03142, InterpolatingFunction[{{1000.46, 1010.55}}, <>]}  *)
```

Chebyshev example:

```
if3 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 100}, InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "Extrapolation"];
if3["InterpolationMethod"]
(*  "Chebyshev"  *)

ifTake[if3, {10.5, 11.5}]
(*  InterpolatingFunction[{{9.03213, 12.7461}}, <>]  *)
```

**Code dump**

`InterpolatingFunction` parts. Execute

```
ifnPart["Properties"] (* OR *)
DownValues[ifnPart][[;; Length@ifnPart["Properties"] + 1]]
```

to see a list of the part names.  Some are valid only for the `"Hermite"` method, some for `"Chebyshev"` or `"Local Taylor Series"`.  The function of some of the parts are as yet unknown to me.  It as complete as my current knowledge, and more than is needed.  But it seemed worth sharing.

```
ClearAll[ifnPart];
ifnPart["Domain"] = Sequence[1];   (*bounding box for domain*)
ifnPart["X1"] = Sequence[1, 1];    (* lower bound for first coordinate *)
ifnPart["X2"] = Sequence[1, 2];    (* upper bound for first coordinate *)
ifnPart["Version"] = Sequence[2, 1]; 
ifnPart["Flags"] = Sequence[2, 2]; (* flags indicating properties:
    bit field positions - inferred, perhaps mistaken
      $extrapolation=0; whether to warn about extrapolation
      $fullArrayBit=1; interpolation data is a full array (not ragged)
      $machPrecBit=2; whether the data (f,f',...) is MachinePrecision
      $repeatedBit=4; whether repeated abscissae are permitted *)
ifnPart["DerivativeOrder"] = Sequence[2, 3]; (*max derivative order*)
ifnPart["NGrid"] = Sequence[2, 4];  (*number of points in each coordinate grid*)
ifnPart["InterpolationOrder"] = Sequence[2, 5]; (*interpolation order*)
ifnPart["Derivative"] = Sequence[2, 6];  (*derivative to evaluate:0-->f[x], 1-->f'[x],...*)
ifnPart["Periodic"] = Sequence[2, 7];
(*ifnPart["??"]=Sequence[2,8];*)
(*ifnPart["??"]=Sequence[2,9];*)
ifnPart["ExtrapolationHandler"] = Sequence[2, 10];
(*ifnPart["??"]=Sequence[2,11];*)
(*ifnPart["??"]=Sequence[2,12];*)
(*ifnPart["??"]=Sequence[2,13];*)
ifnPart["Coordinates"] = Sequence[3];  (*list of lists, abscissae of interpolation grid*)
ifnPart["InterpolationData"] = Sequence[4]; (*interpolation data (values or coefficients)*)
ifnPart["Offsets"] = Sequence[4, 2]; (*offsets in function/derivative array (PackedArrayForm)*)
ifnPart["FlatData"] = Sequence[4, 3]; (*flattened function/derivative values (PackedArrayForm)*)
ifnPart["InterpolationStructure"] = Sequence[5]; (*{Automatic}, or dense output interpolation structure:
   list of types for each unit/subinterval*)
ifnPart["UnitIndices"] = Sequence[5, 1, 1]; (*dense output:
   Indices (to grid) for corresponding coefficients*)
ifnPart["UnitTypes"] = Sequence[5, 1, 2];   (*dense output types:
   Automatic | NDSolve`CubicHermite | NDSolve`LocalSeries | ChebyshevT*)

ifnPart["Properties"] = 
 Cases[DownValues[ifnPart], Verbatim[ifnPart][prop_] :> prop, Infinity];

ifnPart["ValidPartQ", "Chebyshev" | "Local Taylor Series", "UnitIndices" | "UnitTypes", _] := True;
ifnPart["ValidPartQ", _, "UnitIndices" | "UnitTypes", _] := False;
ifnPart["ValidPartQ", "Hermite", "Offsets" | "FlatData", Developer`PackedArrayForm] := True;
ifnPart["ValidPartQ", _, "Offsets" | "FlatData", _] := False;
ifnPart["ValidPartQ", method_String, part_String, _] /; 
 MemberQ[method, "Chebyshev" | "Local Taylor Series" | "Hermite"] &&
  MemberQ[part, ifnPart["Properties"]] := True;
ifnPart["ValidPartQ", _, _, _] := False;
ifnPart[if_InterpolatingFunction, part_String] /; 
   ifnPart["ValidPartQ", if["InterpolationMethod"], part, if[[4, 1]]] :=
  if~Part~ifnPart[part];
```

Taking part of an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
ClearAll[ifTake];
dupeLast[list_] := Append[list, Last@list];
iDataTake["Local Taylor series" | "Chebyshev", data_, span_] := Join[
   {data[[First@span, 1 ;; 2]]}, data[[First@span + 1 ;; Last@span]]
   ];
iDataTake["Hermite", data : {Developer`PackedArrayForm, _, _}, 
   span : {s1_, s2_}] := ReplacePart[
   data,
   {Rest@{ifnPart["Offsets"]} ->
     data[[2, s1 ;; s2 + 1]] - data[[2, s1]],
    Rest@{ifnPart["FlatData"]} ->
     data[[3, data[[2, s1]] + 1 ;; data[[2, s2 + 1]] ]]}
   ];
iDataTake["Hermite", data : {__List}, span_] := data[[Span @@ span]];
iStructureTake["Local Taylor series" | "Chebyshev", structure_, 
   span_] := ReplacePart[structure,
   {Rest@{ifnPart["UnitIndices"]} ->
     Join[
      {{1}},
      1 + structure[[##2 &@ifnPart["UnitIndices"], First@span + 1 ;; Last@span]] - 
        structure[[##2 &@ifnPart["UnitIndices"], First@span, -1]] // 
       dupeLast
      ],
    Rest@{ifnPart["UnitTypes"]} ->
     Join[
      {Automatic},
      structure[[##2 &@ifnPart["UnitTypes"], 
         First@span + 1 ;; Last@span]] // dupeLast
      ]}
   ];
iStructureTake["Hermite", structure_, span_] := structure;
ifTake[if_InterpolatingFunction, {tmin_?NumericQ, tmax_?NumericQ}] /; 
   Length@if["Domain"] == 1 :=
  Module[{coords, newif = Hold @@ if, span, method},
   method = if["InterpolationMethod"];
   coords = First@if["Coordinates"];
   span = Clip[
     SparseArray[UnitStep[coords - tmin] UnitStep[tmax - coords]][
        "AdjacencyLists"][[{1, -1}]] + {-1, 1}, {1, Length@coords}];
   
   newif[[ifnPart["Domain"]]] =
    {coords[[span]]};
   (*newif[[ifnPart[if,"Flags"]]]=??;
     newif[[ifnPart[if, "DerivativeOrder"]}]]=??;*) (* not needed?? *)
   newif[[ifnPart["NGrid"]]] =
    1 + Differences@span;
   newif[[ifnPart["Coordinates"]]] =
    Developer`ToPackedArray@{coords[[Span @@ span]]};
   newif[[ifnPart["InterpolationData"]]] =
    iDataTake[method, if[[ifnPart["InterpolationData"]]], span];
   newif[[ifnPart["InterpolationStructure"]]] =
    iStructureTake[method, if[[ifnPart["InterpolationStructure"]]], span];
   
   InterpolatingFunction @@ newif
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like all of the InterpolatingFunctions I commonly get as solutions to first order initial value problems in `NDSolve` have `InterpolatingMethod` `Hermite`.  `if[[4, 3, ;; ;; 2]]` is a faster equivalent to `if["ValuesOnGrid"]` on the examples I've looked at, but I've already been surprised by the variety of possible structures inside InterpolatingFunctions, so it needs more testing tomorrow.

Comment: Here's an example that generates a `Hermite` `InterpolatingMethod`: `sol = NDSolve[{n'[t] == (Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 1) n[t] - n[t]^2, n[0] == 0.01}, n, {t, 0, 100000}][[1]]`.  `Timing[g1 = (n /. sol)["ValuesOnGrid"];]` is 1 second, but `Timing[g2 = (n /. sol)[[4, 3, ;; ;; 2]];]` is 0.017s, and `g1==g2`.

Answer (score 4):

Most (if not all) of my actual `InterpolatingFunctions` use `InterpolationMethod` `Hermite`, so I tried tweaking @Mr.Wizard's and @MichaelE2's answers to deal with them, while still addressing discontinuous functions too.  In the end, @MichaelE2's [surgical reconstruction approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152861) was easier to get working.  Here's my attempt:

```
ifTake[if_InterpolatingFunction, {tmin_?NumericQ, tmax_?NumericQ}]
  /; if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite" := 
Module[{coords, newif = Hold @@ if, span},
  coords = First@if["Coordinates"];
  span = Clip[SparseArray[UnitStep[coords - tmin] UnitStep[tmax - coords]]["AdjacencyLists"][[{1, -1}]] + {-1, 1}, {1, Length@coords}];
  newif[[1]] = {{tmin, tmax}};
  newif[[2, 4]] = 1 + Differences@span;
  newif[[3]] = Developer`ToPackedArray@{coords[[Span @@ span]]};
  newif[[4, 2]] = if[[4, 2, ;; (span[[2]] - span[[1]]) + 2]];
  newif[[4, 3]] = if[[4, 3, 2 span[[1]] - 1 ;; 2 span[[2]]]];
  InterpolatingFunction @@ newif
];
```

Here's an example that was too slow with my original, naive `InterpolatingFunctionTake`:

```
if = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == (Sin[2 π t] + 1) n[t] - n[t]^2, n[0] == 0.01},
  n, {t, 0, 10^5}][[1]];
if["InterpolationMethod"]
(* Hermite *)

InterpolatingFunctionTake[if, {99000, 100000}] // Timing
(* 5.74 sec *)

ifTake[if, {99900, 100000}] // Timing
(* 0.163 sec *)
```

It also works on my discontinuous example 2 in the original post.  In both cases there is zero difference between the original and trimmed `InterpolatingFunction`.

Some notes:

1. @MichaelE2's trick of not worrying about the precise endpoints is great, but I actually also require the length to be exact.  I used `newif[[1]] = {{tmin, tmax}}` to directly set the domain, which seems to work.
2. I'm assuming that the `InterpolatingFunction` stores only values and first derivatives.  That seems to be the case for all the ones I've seen, but maybe isn't general.
3. Messing with `InterpolatingFunction` internals still seems super sketchy and liable to break with new or old *Mathematica* versions.
4. This took a lot of trial & error, so there still might be issues!

Comment: +1.  I meant to come back to this.  I was trying to think of an approach that would incorporate all the methods elegantly, but other work has delayed it.  I think this method will work only on first-order ODE solutions.  Try it on `NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}]`.  The `PackedArrayForm` can have arbitrary index differences.  (Then there is the unpacked form produced by `Interpolation` but not apparently by `NDSolve`.  One can convert a packed IF to an unpacked one with `if["Unpack"]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing I was worried about.  Cheers for the amazing solution you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

With help from a few clues in @MichaelE2's comments, I think I've solved Problem 2 (discontinuous `InterpolatingFunction`s).  First, define `discontInterpolation` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step/98349#98349).  Then define

```
discontInterpolatingFunctionTake[if_InterpolatingFunction, {xmin_?NumericQ, xmax_?NumericQ}] :=
discontInterpolation[Join[
  {{{xmin}, if[xmin], if'[xmin]}},
  Select[
    Transpose[{{#} & /@ if["Coordinates"][[1]], if["ValuesOnGrid"], if'["ValuesOnGrid"]}],
    xmin < #[[1, 1]] < xmax &],
  {{{xmax}, if[xmax], if'[xmax]}}]];
```

It works perfectly on my problem 2:

```
if = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == 1, n[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], n[t] -> 0]}, n, {t, 0, 2}][[1]]
ift2 = discontInterpolatingFunctionTake[if, {0.5, 1.5}];

Show[
  Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 2}],
  Plot[ift2[t], {t, 0.5, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Pink]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only rub is this solution exacerbates my problem 1 (too slow on large `InterpolatingFunction`s).  On that example,

```
if = n /.
  NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t - 2]), n[0] == 0.1}, n, {t, 0, 20000}, MaxSteps -> ∞][[1]];

discontInterpolatingFunctionTake[if, {0.5, 1.5}]//Timing
(* ~1.5 sec *)
```

Based on another tip from MichaelE2 in chat, it seems that `if["ValuesOnGrid"]` is responsible for the slowness.  Each of the two `ValuesOnGrid`s take ~0.6 sec and the `Select[Transpose[...]]` bit takes ~0.3 sec.

Maybe manual surgery on the `InterpolatingFunction` internals could be a way to speed it up, but those internals are just too complex for me to attempt it myself.

Comment: I see that you already knew about the cost of `"ValuesOnGrid"` and `Select` but I hope you find my answer of value nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of observations.

1. Method `"ValuesOnGrid"` is very slow, and I don't know why.  At least for the example given it can be replaced with a simple [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) extraction.
2. [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) as used is inefficient; a binary search would be better; see: [Finding all elements within a certain range in a sorted list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2369/121)

Applying those methods:

```
Quiet[Needs["Combinatorica`"]]

ifnTake1[
  if_InterpolatingFunction,
  {xmin_?NumericQ, xmax_?NumericQ}
] :=
 Module[{c, v, bs},
   bs = Combinatorica`BinarySearch;
   c = if[[3, 1]];         (* warning: magic numbers *)
   v = if[[4, All, 1]];    (* warning: magic numbers *)
   Join[
     {{xmin, if[xmin]}},
     {c, v}\[Transpose][[⌈bs[c, xmin]⌉ ;; ⌊bs[c, xmax]⌋]],
     {{xmax, if[xmax]}}
   ] // Interpolation
 ]
```

Timings:

```
fn1 = InterpolatingFunctionTake[if, {0.5, 1.5}]; // RepeatedTiming
fn2 = ifnTake1[if, {0.5, 1.5}];                  // RepeatedTiming
fn1 === fn2
```

> ```
> {0.792, Null}
>
> {0.0318, Null}
>
> True
> ```

***Caveat:*** I believe that other InterpolatingFunction expressions have a different internal data structure so this is *not* a general solution as written.  However it would probably be possible to detect these different formats and extract the needed parts accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the start.  Unfortunately I need a general approach that works on any type of `InterpolatingFunction`, which is beyond me right now!

Comment: More generally, a great solution would speed up Method `"ValuesOnGrid"` for all purposes.

Comment: @ChrisK If you provide me with a series of `InterpolatingFunction` expressions to use as a target I shall attempt that.

Comment: @ChrisK, Mr. Wizard: The `"ValuesOnGrid"` is slow on a packed `"Hermite"` interpolation because it stores a potentially ragged array of function, derivative and higher derivative values as a flattened, packed array of those values and a flattened, packed array of indices (suitable for ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` IIRC).  Extracting the values is done in a way that unpacks the values and apparently other arrays (use `On["Packing"]`).