# Extracting part of an Interpolating Function

Tags: interpolation

I get an InterpolatingFunction, call if F1, as a solution to NDSolveValue. I then need to do further operations on this function. However, I only need to work with a small part of the domain of the function. Because of the dimensionality and complexity of the function, these operations are slow if I use the entire function. For example, I can take the gradient of F1 by using Grad[F1[x,y,z],{x,y,z}] which calculates the gradient on the whole domain. But I only need the gradient on a small subset of the domain, and since the gradient is a local operator, I don't need the rest of the function for that.

How can I create a new InterpolatingFunction from the F1 that has a smaller domain than F1?

Comment: perhaps something like `dom = .4 <= # <= .5 && .7 <= #2 <= .75 && 0 <= #3 <= .1 &;F2 = ConditionalExpression[F1[##], dom[##]] &`?

Comment: There's a 1D version of this Q&A somewhere on site (I wrote an answer).  The data structures in an `InterpolatingFunction` depend on the method used to construct it, so code for an MWE (using the same `NDSolve` method etc.) is probably needed.

Comment: Here's the 1D version: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151845/taking-part-of-an-interpolatingfunction