# Is it possible to modify options inside an InterpolationFunction object?

Tags: interpolation

When dealing with a slow function (e.g., a numerical integration) it is sometimes useful to tabulate it and create an interpolation function to work with instead. I found that one can deal with a possible extrapolation issues with `"ExtrapolationHandler"`, e.g.,

```
FInterpolation[f_] := 
 Interpolation[{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[0., 10., 0.1], 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {f[#] &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
```

will return an `InterpolationFunction` object that will use function `f` outside of the interpolation domain. But as far as I can see there is no similar functionality when using `FunctionInterpolation` instead. Naively I'd expect that as the latter returns an `InterpolationFunction` object as well, it should be possible to use

```
ifunc = FunctionInterpolation[f[x], {x, 0., 10.}]
```

and then modify the `"ExtrapolationHandler"` inside `ifunc`. Can one do that somehow?

My workaround was to use

```
FInterpolationExt[func_, domain_] := Module[{ifunc},
  ifunc = FunctionInterpolation[func[x], {x, domain[[1]], domain[[2]]}];
    If[domain[[1]] <= # <= domain[[2]], ifunc[#], func[#] ] & ]
```

which however does not return a simple `InterpolationFunction` (and perhaps is not optimal?).

Comment: The domain of `ifunc` is stored in `ifunc[[1,1]]` . To change it, you, could say: `ifunc[[1,1]]= {new-start,new-end}`

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks, didn't know you can do that! So, by analogy to change the ExtrapolationHandler I can use: `ifunc[[2, 10]] = f[#] &` -- is there a way of adding `"WarningMessage" -> False` as well? It does not work this way: `ifunc[[2, 10]] = {f[#] &, "WarningMessage" -> False}`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151845/taking-part-of-an-interpolatingfunction

Comment: Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81276/4999

Comment: Check out the [interpolation-tag wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/interpolation/info)

Comment: The structure of an `InterpolatingFunction` is explained here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I knew some of the links above, but was unaware that one can simply modify the inside of `InterpolationFunction` like a list. It in essence answers my question. I am new here, how can I give credit for an answer given in a comment? Should I just add a full answer below, refer there to helpful comments and accept it?