# `NDSolve & WhenEvent` return interpolation function with duplicate points ! How to avoid?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

In a simple example I switch the ode depending on two events.

```
V = NDSolveValue[{  v'[t] == (1 - flag[t]) 3.29 - flag[t] 10.8,v[0] == 10, flag[0] == 0
, WhenEvent[v[t] ==    25, flag[t] -> 1]
, WhenEvent[v[t] ==  0 , "StopIntegration"]
} , v, {t, 0, 10 }, DiscreteVariables -> flag[t] ]    ;
```

`NDSolve` seems to work quite good

```
Plot[V[t], {t, 0, V["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, GridLines -> {None, {10, 25}},PlotRange -> {0,30}]
```

[image]

and returns the plotted  (`Hermite`-) interpolation.

Looking inside `V[t]` I get the interpolationdata

```
tv = Transpose[{V["Coordinates"][[1]], V["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
```

**To my surprise there is  a duplicate point inside the interpolation data** `tv`

```
Cases[tv, {___, x_, x_, ___} :> x, All]
(*{{4.55927, 25.}}*)
```

which comes from the first event detection. That means `NDSolve` returns an interpolation object, working quite well, with **duplicate** interpolation points???

**My questions**:

- `V["InterpolationMethod"](*Hemite*)` but `Interpolation[tv, Method ->"Hermite"]` fails. What kind of interpolation is used by `NDSolve` ?
- How could I avoid duplicate points using 'NDSolve& WhenEvent`?

**Thanks!**

Comment: While waiting for an `InterpolatingFunction` guru like @MichaelE2 to show up, I'll just suggest that the duplicate point has the same value, but different derivatives since it is not continuously differentiable.  E.g. `V[[4,3]]` includes the values `25., 3.29, 25., -10.8,`, where I suspect the 25's are the values and the `{3.29, -10.8}` are the derivative.  My own question is rather "can we create such an `InterpolatingFunction` with duplicate points using `Interpolation`?"

Comment: @ChrisK Very interesting idea, thanks! I checked `Map[{#, V[#], V'[#]} &, V["Coordinates"][[1]] ]` which gives identical derivative for the duplicate point. Still waiting for a guru ;-)

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want to avoid it anyhow? It seems harmless under the cover there.

Comment: `(V')["ValuesOnGrid"]` is a better way to extract those derivatives.

Comment: The answer may be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98349/4999 -- An event introduces a singularity or even a discontinuity (typically), and the only way deal with it is to splice together two interpolations.  WRI handled by duplicating the point joining them.

Comment: @ChrisK I don't think it's possible to construct an `InterpolatingFunction` with a duplicate point using `Interpolation`.  It would be helpful if WRI exposed all the functionality of `InterpolatingFunction` through `Interpolation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, we need `InterpolatingFunctionSurgery` to go with `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`.

Comment: @ChrisK Thank you for your helpful comments. In my application I need the interpolation grid to combine several interpolation functions.

Comment: @MichealE2 Thank you your extremely useful link. `NDSolve` seems to use a monotonic Polynom interpolation(pchip).  In my application, which worked in several simulations  without problems, I try to combine simple interpolation function and NDSolve result. Perhaps there exists I direct way to do that...