# Accurate and efficient sampling of interpolated functions

Tags: plotting, interpolation, piecewise

Suppose we are given two interpolated functions

```
f1 = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 2}, {8, -1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
f2 = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 3}, {3, 7}, {4, 2}, {8, 0}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

and one derived function

```
f3 = FunctionInterpolation[f1[t] - f2[t], {t, 0., 8.}];
```

Plotting those functions shows that `f3` is not a very accurate representation of the result.

```
Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f1[t] - f2[t], f3[t]}, {t, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Plot 1]

This can be improved by defining `f3` as follows

```
f3 = FunctionInterpolation[
       f1[t] - f2[t],
       {t, 0., 8.},
       InterpolationPoints -> 300, 
       InterpolationOrder -> 1
     ];
```

but at the cost of oversampling.

[image: Plot 2]

A simple but rather hacky way to represent `f3` more accurately without oversampling is

```
f3 = Interpolation[
       Cases[Plot[f1[t] - f2[t], {t, 0, 8}], Line[_], Infinity][[1, 1]],
       InterpolationOrder -> 1
     ]
```

I also tried to construct an `InterpolatingFunction` from `MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[f1[t] - f2[t] == y, {{t, 0, 8}, {y, -6, 3}}]`. However, this does not work out of the box because points are duplicated due to the presence of discontinuities.

How would you approach the problem?

**Update:** The following use case is one example where accurate and efficient sampling is necessary. Suppose the dependent variable represents a date (`AbsoluteTime[DateObject[...]]`) and the goal is to construct a `TimeSeries` object of `f1[t] + f2[t]` that takes interpolation into account.

Comment: Why not directly using `f1[t] - f2[t]`?

Comment: What is the desired output? Please [edit] your question and elaborate more about what exactly are the specific features of the answer you are after.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step

Comment: It seems to me that `f1[t] + f2[t]` takes interpolation into account and could be used to construct a time series at arbitrary values of `t`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, @ cvgmt's suggestion `f3[t_] := f1[t] - f2[t]` seems the easiest and most efficient way to proceed.

Second, here's a way for those who wish to do it anyway:
Using `discontInterpolation[]` from [Interpolating data with a step](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step/98349#98349), we get this:

```
f1 = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 2}, {8, -1}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0];
f2 = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 3}, {3, 7}, {4, 2}, {8, 0}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

grid = Union[f1@"Grid", f2@"Grid"];
dupegrid = Riffle[Most@grid, Rest@grid];
fpieces =
  Subtract @@ {f1@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #], 
      f2@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #]} & /@ Rest@grid;
dfpieces = D[fpieces, x];
fvals = MapThread[ReplaceAll,
    {fpieces, Partition[{x -> #} & @@@ grid, 2, 1]}] // Flatten;
dfvals = MapThread[ReplaceAll,
    {dfpieces, Partition[{x -> #} & @@@ grid, 2, 1]}] // Flatten;

f3 = discontInterpolation[Transpose@{dupegrid, fvals, dfvals}];

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image]

The two functions `f1` and `f2` do not have to have the same grid. You need the derivatve values to make the discontinuous interpolation work (AFAIR, an apparent and undocumented requirement of `InterpolatingFunction`), so you're stuck with a minimum order-3 interpolation; otherwise, it uses a minimal grid and sampling. Since we control the derivatives, the cubic polynomials in the interpolant turn out to have coefficients of zero on the quadratic and cubic terms. So in effect, it's a linear interpolation, just as it appears in the plot.

Manual construction of an `InterpolatingFunction` is sorta **DANGEROUS**. **SAVE YOUR WORK** before you try it. Since there isn't safe access to the full functionality of `InterpolatingFunction`, there's not much choice.  Perhaps someone could get `NDSolve[]` to construct `f1[t] - f2[t]`.

Answer (score 0):

What about (see @cvgmt's comment)

```
f3=f1&-f2&
```

Comment: I updated my post to motivate the sampling use case.

Comment: I suppose you realize that `f1&-f2&` is not a function nor equivalent to @cvgmt's suggestion?