# Incompatible InterpolatingFunction between V9 (and earlier) and V10

Tags: bugs, interpolation, compatibility

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

I am encountering compatibility issues when loading `DumpSave`(d) definitions in V10 that have been created with earlier versions. V10 appears to be unable to digest `InterpolatingFunction from earlier version. When looking at an example functions in both versions I get the following:

Definition from the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html)

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
ifun = Interpolation[points]
```

In V9.0.1 this is digested as:

```
??ifun
Global`ifun
ifun=InterpolatingFunction[{{0,5}},{4,3,0,{6},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic},{{0,1,2,3,4,5}},{{0},{1},{3},{4},{3},{0}},{Automatic}]
```

In V10:

```
??ifun
Global`ifun
ifun=InterpolatingFunction[{{0,5}},{4,3,0,{6},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{0,1,2,3,4,5}},{{0},{1},{3},{4},{3},{0}},{Automatic}]
```

Particularly the second part is not identical:

V9.0.1:

```
ifun[[2]]
{4,3,0,{6},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic}
```

V10:

```
ifun[[2]]
{4,3,0,{6},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False}
```

Can somebody explain the differences to me? Is there a way to still be able to use the old definitions (which were time consuming to create) in V10?

Comment: The V10 documentation doesn't mention any modifications since V3, but this is clearly bogus. I think the changes were made to support the new output format for interpolation functions that V10 implemented. I like the new output format.

Comment: @m_Goldberg I agree, the new output format is nice. However, I also like my old InterpolatingFunctions and i would like to Keep using them :)

Comment: But what can you do except rebuild them? WRI giveth and WRI taketh away. I guess I advise complaining to WRI tech support.

Comment: This is a bug and seems to be fixed in the upcoming V10.0.1 release.

Comment: @user21 Do you have any more information on this? Such as when V10.0.1 is going to be released. While I like the fix Mr.Wizard suggest, it would be nice if it works out of the box.

Comment: @theDriver, my guess is more on the order of weeks than month.

Comment: @Markus Can you confirm that this is fixed in 10.0.1?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Look's like it's fixed now in V10.0.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following [How to splice together several instances of InterpolatingFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction/19043#19043) which I updated earlier today, before seeing this question, there are several new Properties for `InterpolatingFunction` expressions in version 10:

```
v7 = {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "Evaluate", "Grid", 
   "InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", "Methods", "Properties", "ValuesOnGrid"};

v10 = {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", "Evaluate", "Grid", 
   "InterpolationMethod", "InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", "Methods", 
   "OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", "PlottableQ", "Properties", "QuantityUnits", 
   "ValuesOnGrid"};

Complement[v10, v7]
```

> ```
> {"ElementMesh", "InterpolationMethod", "OutputDimensions",
>  "Periodicity", "PlottableQ", "QuantityUnits"}
> ```

I suspect that the additional parameters correlate one or more of these.  Proceeding with that assumption I searched for a mapping and found:

```
test1 = Array[{Quantity[#, "Second"], Quantity[#^2, "Meters"]} &, 10] // Interpolation;

test1[[2]]
test1["QuantityUnits"]
test1["PlottableQ"]
```

> ```
> {4, 3, 0, {10}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {"Seconds"}, "Meters", True}
>
> {{"Seconds"}, "Meters"}
>
> True
> ```

Older `InterpolatingFunction` expressions should not have any units associated (I believe) therefore you should always be able to use `{},{}` for those parameters.  Apparently `"PlottableQ"` is `False` unless there are units so you should be able to use `False` there as well.

```
ifun9 = InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 5}}, {4, 3, 0, {6}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    Automatic}, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {3}, {0}}, {Automatic}];

ifunFixed = MapAt[Join[#, {{}, {}, False}] &, ifun9, 2];

Plot[ifunFixed[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!