# Can I use the values of interpolating points from NDSolve's output? And How?‎

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

The output of `NDSolve` is a (list of)`InterpolatingFunction`(s). In standard output format the ‎elements of interpolation are not printed explicitly. I want to know if there is any way to access these ‎values?‎
I need to obtain the value of the solution of an ODE system, at the endpoint of the interval, let's say`‎t=‎3`‎. I use `NDSolve` as follows: ‎
[image]
The output is a vector of `InterpolatingFunction`s. When I put the answers vector in  `Psi[t]`(a vector of functions of `t`) and ‎then replace the variable `t` by 3, it seems that *Mathematica* starts interpolating all functions and ‎then replaces `t=‎‏3`‎.‎
But for some large systems (more than ‎*‏30000‏* x *‏30000‏‎*). this procedure becomes unbearably time ‎consuming or even impossible for a PC (*Corei‏5‏ & ‎‏4‏GB of RAM*) to perform. Thus, if both of the ‎interpolating points and the corresponding values be available (at least at boundary points), they ‎can be used instead, much more simply.‎

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 9 you can use `Part` to access the parts of an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
ifun = Interpolation[points]
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0,5}},<>] *)

{ifun[[3]], ifun[[4]]}
(* {{{0,1,2,3,4,5}},{{0},{1},{3},{4},{3},{0}}} *)
```

You can also access `Properties` of `ifun` using (not `ifun["Properties"]` as one would expect) `ifun["Methods"]`:

```
ifun["Methods"]
(* {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", 
     "Evaluate", "Grid", "InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", 
     "Methods", "Properties", "ValuesOnGrid"} *)

{ifun["Coordinates"][[1]], ifun["ValuesOnGrid"]}
(* {{0,1,2,3,4,5}, {0,1,3,4,3,0}} *)
```

Using the above with `NDSolve`

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
(* {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,30.}},<>]}} *)
if1 = s[[1, All, -1]]
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,30.}},<>] *)

{if1["Coordinates"][[1]], if1["ValuesOnGrid"]} // Short
(* {{0.,0.00017069,0.00034138,<<332>>,29.7515,29.8757,30.},{<<1>>}}*)

coords = Transpose[{if1["Coordinates"][[1]], if1["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
ListPlot[coords]
```

[image]

Related Q/As:

[How to splice together several instances of InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/125)

[Incompatible InterpolatingFunction between V9 and v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57608/125)

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I've tried it, but even for a partly small example that I've solved before in less than 5 seconds, this syntax caused to an immediate memory overflow! A note I should stated before is that I'm using Mathematica 8.0 .

Comment: Would you explain that why you've used the term : if1 = s[[1, -1, -1]]? I think I'm misusing this part of syntax.

Comment: @Toughee, despite the typo (it was meant to be `s[[1,1,-1]]`) this syntax happens to work fine with a single function `y`. However, the correct form that works in general is `s[[1,All,-1]]`. It is an alternative to `{x,y,z}/. s //First` to get the right-hand-sides of `Rule`s inside `s`.

Comment: By v11.3, `ifun["Methods"]` has grown to `{"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", 
"Evaluate", "GetPolynomial", "Grid", "InterpolationMethod", 
"InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", "Methods", 
"OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", "PlottableQ", "Properties", 
"QuantityUnits", "Unpack", "ValuesOnGrid"}`.