Extracting the interpolating solution function from NDSolve
Using NDSolve I obtain a numerical solution to a two dimensional system of ODEs.
x = 1;
\[Epsilon] = 1/2^(1 + 2);


sol = NDSolve[{\[Mu]'[
      t] - (-8 \[Epsilon] (Sinh[\[Mu][t]])^3 Sin[k[t]] Cos[k[t]] Sum[
        Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)]/(
         Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 1 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - 1 - x)]) (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu][
              t]])^2/(Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)])^2) (Sinh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - x)]/(
          Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 2 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
              t]*(n - 2 - x)])), {n, -5, 5}]) == 0,
   k'[t] - (-2 \[Epsilon] (Sinh[\[Mu][
          t]])^2 (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu][t]])^2) (1 + (Sin[k[t]])^2) Sum[(
         Tanh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)])/(
         Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 1 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - 1 - x)]) (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu][
              t]])^2/(Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)])^2) (Cosh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - x)]/(
          Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 2 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
              t]*(n - 2 - x)])), {n, -5, 5}]) == 0, \[Mu][0] == 1, 
   k[0] == 0.05}, {\[Mu], k}, {t, 0, 50}]
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{Log[k[t]], Log[\[Mu][t]]} /. sol], {t, 0, 50}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Log[k]", "Log[\[Mu]]"}]

I want to examine the pairs $(\mu,k)$ per time step. However, I do not know how to extract the interpolating function that NDSolve returns. How can I obtain this data?

What is wrong with what you did? (you just added log). You can also try ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{k[t],\[Mu][t]}]/. sol,{t,0,3}] without log. If you want table of data, may be Table[Evaluate[{k[t],\[Mu][t]}]/.sol,{t,0,1,.1}] There is no need to extract the interpolating function from NDSolve result, as the result is already an interpolating function .

The following sentences look confusing: "I want to examine the pairs $(\mu,k)$ per time step. However, I do not know how to extract the interpolating function that NDSolve returns." Do you actually mean you want to extract the discrete data inside InterpolatingFunction[...]? If so, check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60375/1871

I feel I've done this many times, but I didn't find it:
{\[Mu]["ValuesOnGrid"], k["ValuesOnGrid"]} /. First[sol] // Transpose
(*
{{1., 0.05}, 
 {1., 0.0500009},
 {1., 0.0500017},
 {1.00008, 0.0508492},
 {1.00017, 0.0516964},
 {1.00026, 0.0525432},
 {1.00034, 0.0533896},
 {1.00043, 0.0542356},
 {1.00052, 0.0550812},
 {1.00062, 0.0559264},
 {1.00071, 0.0567713},
 {1.0008,  0.0576149},
 {1.0009,  0.058458}}
*)

