# Having trouble solving a particular differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics

I have the following equation:

$$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\left(f(x) + \frac{1+(f'(x))^2}{f''(x)}\right) = c$$

where $c$ is a constant $> 0$.

Mathematica handles this well and I'm able to plot it just fine using `NDSolve`, but only when $c = 0$. For any other value of $c$, I get errors and the plot comes out all wrong.

Can anyone help me here?

#### Edit

An example of the code I used for NDSolve was:

```
s = 
  NDSolve[
   {y[x]/y'[x] * (y[x] + (1+(y'[x])^2)/y''[x]) == 1, y[0] == 10, y'[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

Comment: Can you give the `NDSolve[]` code you used so people don't have to retype things for you?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Sorry, I've added it now.

Comment: I don't have any trouble evaluating your example expression. I running V11.3 on macOS 10.13.4. I suggest you try relaunching Mathematica and try with a fresh notebook.

Comment: @m_goldberg That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that the problem might be with plotting, which is discussed in
[Easy way to plot ODE solutions from NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve)
The following works without messages.

```
ListLinePlot@
 NDSolveValue[{y[x]/y'[x]*(y[x] + (1 + (y'[x])^2)/y''[x]) == 1, 
   y[0] == 10, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image]