# System of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I used the following commands:

```
s = NDSolve[{X'[t] == 10 (X[t] - Y[t]), 
   Y'[t] == X[t] (28 - Z[t]) - Y[t], Z'[t] == X[t] Y[t] - (8/3) Z[t], 
   X[0] == Y[0] == Z[0] == 0.001}, {X, Y, Z}, {t, 100}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 100}]
```

but I am not sure if I am right, the results are strange. Am I right? How can I plot $X,Y,Z?$

Comment: Try restricting the `PlotRange`: `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> 40]` -- looks like it then goes off to infinity instead of getting orbiting another critical point.

Comment: nice, is the command "s=..." right? How can i plot $X,Y,Z$?

Comment: Do you mean separately? Use `Plot`, look in the documentation for `NDSolve`, or look at these examples: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve

Comment: the link doesn't help me. I am trying to understand, I am a beginner. I used https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html, but I need to plot them in one graph

Comment: Did you try replacing `ParametricPlot3D` with `Plot`? -- Also, if you want the Lorenz system, I think the first equation has X and Y switched.

Answer (score 3):

As long as this system is the Lorenz attractor, you have a changed sign in the first equation, so it blows up. Now it is fixed.

```
s = Quiet @ NDSolve[{X'[t] == -10 (X[t] - Y[t]), Y'[t] == X[t] (28 - Z[t]) - Y[t], Z'[t] == X[t] Y[t] - (8/3) Z[t], X[0] == Y[0] == Z[0] == 1/100}, {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 10}]
```