# Numerically solve the Rayleigh-Plesset equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I've been trying to numerically solve the modified Rayleigh-Plesset equation (eq. 5 from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.5531.pdf) using the same parameters as in the papers. This is my code

```
S = 72.8*10^-3;
ro = 1000;
y = 5/3;
c = 1500;
mu = 1.002*10^-3;
P0 = 101325;
R0 = 2.0*10^-6;
h = R0/8.86;
F = 26.5;
w = 2*Pi*F;
Pa = 0;
P[t_] = -Pa*P0*Sin[w*t];
sol = NDSolve[
   {ro*(R[t]*R''[t] + 3/2*(R'[t])^2) == 
     Pgas[t] - P0 - P[t] - 4 mu*R'[t]/R[t] - 2 S/R[t] + 
      R[t]/c*Pgas'[t],
    Pgas[t] == (P0 + 2 S/R0)*((R0^3 - h^3)/((R[t])^3 - h^3))^y,
    R[0] == R0, R'[0] == 0
    }, R[t], {t, 0, 1/F}];
```

I use the [`TwoAxisPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html) function from Wolfram How-to to plot the results.

When Pa = 0, the results are correct (the R remains constant and equals to R0)

[image: Pa=0]

When Pa = 10^-6 (which is extremely small), the result are also correct - radius oscillates in the anti-phase with pressure

[image: Pa=10^-6]

But with the adequate values of Pa (e.g. 1/10), I get "NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions". It should look something like Fig. 2-4 from related paper..

I wonder how to deal with it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here.

1. By throwing the definition of $p_\text{gas}$ directly into `NDSolve`, you're solving the system as a DAE system, but the DAE solver of `NDSolve` is generally weaker than its ODE solver. So we need to substitute the definition of $p_\text{gas}$ into the modified Rayleigh-Plesset equation.
2. There's a typo in the table of parameters in the paper, and you don't correct it correctly. The line $f = 1/T = 26\color{red}{,} 5\ \text{Hz}$ is obviously strange, and you think it should be $f=26.5\ \text{Hz}$, but just look at the other parameters, how can such a low frequency lead to an oscilation happened in the scale of $\mu s$? Taking this into consideration, it's not hard to guess the correct $f$ is $f=26,500\ \text{Hz}$.

The following is the fixed code. Technique mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/1871) is used for plotting the result.

```
S = 72.8 10^-3;
ro = 1000;
y = 5/3;
c = 1500;
mu = 1.002 10^-3;
P0 = 101325;
R0 = 2.0 10^-6;
h = R0/8.86;
F = 26500;
w = 2 Pi F;
Pa = coef P0;
P[t_] = -Pa Sin[w t];
Pgas = (P0 + (2 S)/R0) ((R0^3 - h^3)/(R[t]^3 - h^3))^y;
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ro (R[t] R''[t] + 3/2 R'[t]^2) == 
     Pgas - P0 - P[t] - (4 mu R'[t])/R[t] - (2 S)/R[t] + (R[t] D[Pgas, t])/c, R[0] == R0,
     R'[0] == 0}, R, {t, 0, 80 10^-6}, coef];
```

The following reproduces **Figure 2**:

```
ListLinePlot[psol@#, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/5] & /@ {1.2, 1.3, 1.35, 
   1.4} // GraphicsColumn
```

[image]

**Figure 3**:

```
ListLinePlot[psol[#]', PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/5] & /@ {1.2, 1.3, 1.35, 
   1.4} // GraphicsColumn
```

[image]

**Figure 4**:

```
ListLinePlot[psol[1.42], PlotRange -> {{0, 40 10^-6}, All}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

"12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
```

For

```
Pa = 101325/10;
P[t_] = -Pa*P0*Sin[w*t];
sol = NDSolve[{ro*(R[t]*R''[t] + 3/2*(R'[t])^2) == 
     Pgas[t] - P0 - P[t] - 4 mu*R'[t]/R[t] - 2 S/R[t] + 
      R[t]/c*Pgas'[t], 
    Pgas[t] == (P0 + 2 S/R0)*((R0^3 - h^3)/((R[t])^3 - h^3))^y, 
    R[0] == R0, R'[0] == 0}, R[t], {t, 0, 1/F}];
TwoAxisPlot[{Evaluate[R[t] /. sol], D[Evaluate[R[t] /. sol], t]}, {t, 
  0, 1/F}]
```

[image: Plot]

So it seems to be an error of the longer session making this work.

Possible ClearAll["Global'*"] remove the problem.

But I have to admit:

[image: picture with the warnings]

These are ivres and mconly for NDSolve

and

dmval for InterpolationFunction.

The second one is for outside of domain value inputs.

Somehow a closely related question is [dynamic euler bernoulli beam equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997). The path is enter better initial conditions and use the options of `NDSolve` appropriate.

What is Pgas?

```
S = 72.8*10^-3;
ro = 1000;
y = 5/3;
c = 1500;
mu = 1.002*10^-3;
P0 = 101325;
R0 = 2.0*10^-6;
h = R0/8.86;
F = 26.5;
w = 2*Pi*F;
Pa = 0.1(*101325/10*);
P[t_] = -Pa*P0*Sin[w*t];
sol = NDSolve[{ro*(R[t]*R''[t] + 3/2*(R'[t])^2) == 
     Pgas[t] - P0 - P[t] - 4 mu*R'[t]/R[t] - 2 S/R[t] + 
      R[t]/c*Pgas'[t], 
    Pgas[t] == (P0 + 2 S/R0)*((R0^3 - h^3)/((R[t])^3 - h^3))^y, 
    R[0] == R0, R'[0] == 0}, {R, Pgas}, {t, 0, 1/F}];
TwoAxisPlot[Flatten@Evaluate[{R[t], Pgas[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1/F}]
```

Leads me to the error message from the question. I calculated for a solution for `Pgas` with `NDSolve` too.

The message depends strongly on the value of `Pa`.

For `Pa=0.01` the message is NDSolve:ivres.

The cause is that this is not a system of ordinary differential equations anymore.

Change to

```
ClearAll[Pa]

S = 72.8*10^-3;
ro = 1000;
y = 5/3;
c = 1500;
mu = 1.002*10^-3;
P0 = 101325;
R0 = 2.0*10^-6;
h = R0/8.86;
F = 26.5;
w = 2*Pi*F;
(*Pa=0.01(*101325/10*);*)
P[t_, Pa_] = -Pa*P0*Sin[w*t];
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ro*(R[t]*R''[t] + 3/2*(R'[t])^2) == 
     Pgas[t] - P0 - P[t, Pa] - 4 mu*R'[t]/R[t] - 2 S/R[t] + 
      R[t]/c*Pgas'[t], 
    Pgas[t] == (P0 + 2 S/R0)*((R0^3 - h^3)/((R[t])^3 - h^3))^y, 
    R[0] == R0, R'[0] == 0}, {R, Pgas}, {t, 0, 1/F}, {Pa}];
```

[image: output of ParametricNDSolve]

With ParametricNDSolve no message appears. But the evaluation has to be done more carefully. The problem to me is that the Mathematica documentation deals only with `x[t]`-type problems with a parameter. This shows for a general Pa a solution exists.

More thought on Pa and its possible and successful physical values is in need.

```
Plot[{R[0][t], Pgas[0][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1/F}]
```

[image: output Plot for Pa=0]

```
F = 26.5; Manipulate[
 Plot[{R[Pa][t], Pgas[Pa][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1/F}], {Pa, 0, 0.02}]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

This shows a flat goes over into a wavy solution and `Pgas` is flat. This does not calculate the border, limit of maximum `Pgas`, `Pa` for which a solution exists and what is to alter for higher `Pgas`, `Pa` values.

The critical value for `Pa` is now somewhere above 1.3 and lower than 1.31 with ParametricNDSolve.

[image: output]

Above this value the ondulation of the solutions gets a zero around t=0.01 and gets after that unphysical.

Comment: (-1) This isn't even a hint for OP's question.