# plot multiple curves : solution obtained from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation, finite-element-method

I want to plot the solution obtained from NDSolve as a multicurve plot like shown in the
following sample image (image [ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/58343)). Here, x1, x2 , x3, x4 .. are the solution computed at `includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}}` in my case.

[image]

In the following code ([ref](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/37536/29087)):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = Line[{{0}, {100}}];
includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints, 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0008]
vars = {c[t, x], t, {x}};
RegularizedDeltaPoint[g_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ Thread[1/(4 g) (1 + Cos[\[Pi]/(2 g) (X - Xs)])],
     And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 g]}, {0, True}}]
Subscript[h, mesh] = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
Subscript[gamma, reg] = Subscript[h, mesh]/2;
temp = RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[gamma, reg], {x}, 
   includePoints[[1]]];
parameters = {kappa -> {{910}}, v1 -> 162, 
   gamma -> Subscript[gamma, reg], Qp -> 1.5};
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[
        Div][(-kappa).Inactive[Grad][
         c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1}.Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] + 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {10}] == 0, 
    c[0, x] == 1} /. parameters;

tEnd = 2;
cfun = NDSolveValue[{pde, DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == 5, x == 0]}, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} \[Element] mesh];
Manipulate[
 Plot[cfun[t, x], {x} \[Element] region, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 5}}], {t, 0, tEnd}]
```

[image]

The above figure displays solution vs x-position. Instead, I want to plot solution curves observed at x-positions in `includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}};` as a function of time. as a function of time.

Suggestions will be really appreciated.

EDIT:

1. May I also know how to save the solution in cfun at includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}} over the integration time span to a text file?
2. Using the following command

   With[{i = Flatten[includePoints]},
   Plot[Evaluate[cfun[t, #] & /@ i], {t, 0, tEnd},
   PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {0, 5}},
   PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ i)]]

I could generate,
[image]

But I am not sure why c(t,0), the first point which is the left boundary isn't at 5 (Dirichlet conditioned defined) at t=0. Could someone please have a look?
Also, the legend labels aren't formatted correctly String Template appears as text in the legend).

Comment: @Michael E2 Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Try including the Dirichlet condition in a list with the PDE, like this `cfun = NDSolveValue[{pde, DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == 5, x == 0]}, 
   c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} \[Element] mesh];`

Comment: @LouisB Thank you, I tried the above but it is still not clear to me how the plot can be generated. Could you please explain a bit more? Or, may I know how to save the solution in `cfun` at `includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}}` over the integration time span to a text file?

Comment: This question is a continuation of a question [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/37531/11893)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update to fix boundary and initial condition inconsistency

Your `"MaxCellMeasure"` is much more refined than it needs to be. Furthermore, you will note that the initial condition and the `DirichletCondition` are inconsistent. This causes the `DirichletCondition` to be ignored. One way to remove this inconsistency is to rapidly ramp up the `DirichletCondition` from the initial condition to its desired value.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = Line[{{0}, {100}}];
includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1];
vars = {c[t, x], t, {x}};
RegularizedDeltaPoint[g_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ Thread[1/(4 g) (1 + Cos[π/(2 g) (X - Xs)])],
     And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 g]}, {0, True}}]
Subscript[h, mesh] = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
Subscript[gamma, reg] = Subscript[h, mesh]/2;
temp = RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[gamma, reg], {x}, 
   includePoints[[1]]];
parameters = {kappa -> {{910}}, v1 -> 162, 
   gamma -> Subscript[gamma, reg], Qp -> 1.5};
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[Div][(-kappa) . 
        Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1} . 
       Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] + 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {10}] == 0, c[0, x] == 1} /. 
   parameters;

tEnd = 2;
cfun = NDSolveValue[
   pde~Join~{DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == 4 (1 - Exp[-1000 t]) + 1, 
      x == 0]}, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} ∈ mesh];
With[{i = Flatten[{0}~Join~includePoints]}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[cfun[t, #] & /@ i], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {0, 5.1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ i)]]
ListPlot[Table[cfun[t, x], {x, 0, 100, 10}, {t, 0, tEnd, tEnd/100}], 
 Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, tEnd}]
```

[image: Solution with fixed inconsistency]

## Original answer

Here is one way you could plot the solutions:

```
With[{i = Flatten[includePoints]},
 Plot[Evaluate[cfun[t, #] & /@ i], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {0, 5}}, 
  PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ i)]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, works great. Sorry for another question. Could you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: @Natasha If I quit the kernel and copy the code from your post, I get the image shown in my answer. Unless you changed the definition of `includePoints`, `0` should not be there. 
 What `$Version` of _Mathematica_ are you using?

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer :) . I'm using version 12.0

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249965/what-is-the-units-of-source-term) post?

Comment: Is there an option to specify `MinCellMeasure` ? Could you please have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250264/defining-mesh-size-for-ndsolve) post?