# What is the units of source term

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

This is a follow up to my previous question posted here,
I'm setting up a pde in 1D to simulate the convection-diffusion physics along with point sinks

```
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][(-kappa).Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1}.Inactive[
      Grad][c[t, x], {x}] + 
   Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {12.4}]
```

I went through the documentation given [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#945943234) where the units of the heat source term is detailed for 1D, 2D or 3D simulation. But how the units od Qp are considered isn't very clear to me.

I would like to confirm whether the units for 1D simulation is in mol/l/s .

Comment: Natasha, I am only commenting to note that the SE system is not set up to tag a user that has not commented on the post prior, as you attempt to do here. Perhaps you may have some luck tagging them on the chat page for this SE site.

Comment: Natasha, the function `RegularizedDeltaPoint` is not a built-in function in Mma. It is introduced in the tutorial you mentioned. Please note that you have to first evaluate its definition to start solving afterwards. Further, according to its definition, this function is dimensionless by itself. Therefore, the dimension of `Qp` is the same as one of any other terms of the equation. For example, it is the same as the dimension of dc/dt. That is, [1/(m^3 s)] is you use the units typical in physics or [mol/(l s)] if you use chemical units.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thanks for letting me know. I have removed it :)