# Defining mesh size for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation, finite-element-method, mesh

I want to see the effect of mesh size on the solution curves while simulating convection-diffusion - point sink via NDSolve FEM.

In the following code ([ref](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/37536/29087) also related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249900/plot-multiple-curves-solution-obtained-from-ndsolve) post):

I'd like to know how to visualize the mesh size distribution i.e mesh element size defined in `mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints,  "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1];`. Also, from what I read [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html), I understand `MaxCellMeasure` sets the upper limit of the mesh element size. I want to know if there is a similar option
for defining the minimum size of mesh elements. e.g. `MinCellMeasure` argument ? I couldn't find this in the documentation.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = Line[{{0}, {100}}];
includePoints = {{10}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1];
vars = {c[t, x], t, {x}};
RegularizedDeltaPoint[g_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ Thread[1/(4 g) (1 + Cos[\[Pi]/(2 g) (X - Xs)])],
     And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 g]}, {0, True}}]
Subscript[h, mesh] = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
Subscript[gamma, reg] = Subscript[h, mesh]/2;
temp = RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[gamma, reg], {x}, 
   includePoints[[1]]];
parameters = {kappa -> {{1000}}, v1 -> 100, 
   gamma -> Subscript[gamma, reg], Qp -> 3};
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[
        Div][(-kappa).Inactive[Grad][
         c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1}.Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] + 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {10}] == 0, 
    c[0, x] == 1} /. parameters;

tEnd = 3;
cfun = NDSolveValue[
   pde~Join~{DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == 4 (1 - Exp[-1000 t]) + 1, 
      x == 0]}, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} \[Element] mesh];
With[{i = Flatten[{0}~Join~includePoints]}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[cfun[t, #] & /@ i], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {0, 5.1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ i)]]
ListPlot[Table[cfun[t, x], {x, 0, 100, 10}, {t, 0, tEnd, tEnd/100}], 
 Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, tEnd}]
```

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 8):

There is no `MinCellMeasure`, but you can build your own mesh, thereby giving you complete control over the discretization. I will show an example of how to do this at the end of the post. With respect to mesh visualization, your current mesh is pretty finely discretized, making it difficult to view the distributions. Also, your parameters make it difficult to see your point source term. So, let us make some parameter changes (coarsen the mesh, lower the diffusivity and velocity, and crank up the point source term) to better visualize some of the features I think the OP wants to capture.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = Line[{{0}, {100}}];
includePoints = {{10}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 5];
vars = {c[t, x], t, {x}};
RegularizedDeltaPoint[g_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ Thread[1/(4 g) (1 + Cos[π/(2 g) (X - Xs)])],
     And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 g]}, {0, True}}]
hmesh = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
gammareg = hmesh/2;
temp = RegularizedDeltaPoint[gammareg, {x}, includePoints[[1]]];
parameters = {kappa -> {{1}}, v1 -> 10, gamma -> gammareg, Qp -> 10};
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[Div][(-kappa) . 
        Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1} . 
       Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] + 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {10}] == 0, c[0, x] == 1} /. 
   parameters;

tEnd = 3;
cfun = NDSolveValue[
   pde~Join~{DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == 4 (1 - Exp[-1000 t]) + 1, 
      x == 0]}, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} ∈ mesh];
With[{i = Flatten[{0}~Join~includePoints]}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[cfun[t, #] & /@ i], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {-0.5, 5.1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ i), Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Concentration", None}, {"Time", 
     "Concentrations @ 0 an 10 x units"}}]]
ListPlot[Table[cfun[t, x], {x, 0, 100, 10}, {t, 0, tEnd, tEnd/100}], 
 Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, tEnd}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {-0.5, 5.1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ Subdivide[100, 10]), 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Concentration", None}, {"Time", 
    "Concentrations every 10 x units"}}]
Plot[cfun[0.01, x], x ∈ mesh, 
 PlotRange -> {{9, 11}, {0.4, 1.05}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Concentration", None}, {"X", 
    "Concentration near x=10 for small time"}}]
```

[image: Coarse solution]

Because the mesh is so coarse, `NDSolve` complains about high Péclet numbers.

## Mesh visualization

For a 1D mesh, you could use `ListPlot` on the mesh coordinates, or you can convert the mesh into a `MeshRegion` and use [`HighlightMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightMesh.html) to visualize the discretization.

```
ListPlot[Union@Flatten@mesh["Coordinates"], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Node Position", None}, {"Node ID", 
    "Node Position vs Node ID"}}]
HighlightMesh[MeshRegion@mesh, 0]
```

[image: Coarse mesh discretization]

## Anisotropic meshing

In my answer here [240408](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240408/61809), there are many links to examples where I have answered questions using an anisotropic meshing approach. This approach will allow you to capture very sharp features without much computational expense.

### Helper functions

First, we will define some helper functions to create the anisotropic mesh.

```
(*Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Meshes*)
pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[
     firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 0.00000001, 
      100000000/fElm}, Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l];
leftSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm0[len, n, fElm]
rightSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Module[{seg}, seg = leftSegmentGrowth[len, n, fElm];
  flipSegment[seg]]
reflectRight[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
```

### Build an anisotropic mesh

The above helper functions allow build anisotropic mesh segments and glue them together. The following will create an anisotropic mesh with refinements at 0 and to either side of 10.

```
(*Define some parameters*)
x1 = 10; x2 = 90; nelm1 = 40; nelm2 = 50;
(*Create mesh segment with finer mesh at x=0 and 10*)
seg1 = reflectRight@leftSegmentGrowth[x1/2, nelm1, x1/200];
Print["Left of 10 domain"]
r1 = pointsToMesh@seg1
seg2 = leftSegmentGrowth[x2, nelm2, x1/200];
Print["Right of 10"]
r2 = pointsToMesh@seg2
Print["Full domain"]
regfull = pointsToMesh@extendMesh[seg1, seg2]
(*Extract Coords from region*)
crd = MeshCoordinates[regfull];
(*Create element mesh*)
mesh = ToElementMesh[crd];
Print["Coordinate positions on a log scale"]
ListLogPlot[Transpose@mesh["Coordinates"], PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Node Position", None}, {"Node ID", 
    "Node Position vs Node ID"}}]
```

[image: Anisotropic mesh]

### Solve on an anisotropic mesh

```
gammareg = hmesh/400;
temp = RegularizedDeltaPoint[gammareg, {x}, includePoints[[1]]];
parameters = {kappa -> {{1}}, v1 -> 10, gamma -> gammareg, Qp -> 10};
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[Div][(-kappa) . 
        Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1} . 
       Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] + 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {10}] == 0, c[0, x] == 1} /. 
   parameters;

tEnd = 3;
cfun = NDSolveValue[
   pde~Join~{DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == 4 (1 - Exp[-1000 t]) + 1, 
      x == 0]}, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} ∈ mesh];
With[{i = Flatten[{0}~Join~includePoints]}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[cfun[t, #] & /@ i], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {-0.5, 5.1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ i), Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Concentration", None}, {"Time", 
     "Concentrations @ 0 an 10 x units"}}]]
ListPlot[Table[cfun[t, x], {x, 0, 100, 10}, {t, 0, tEnd, tEnd/100}], 
 Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, tEnd}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {-0.5, 5.1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["c(t,``)"] /@ Subdivide[100, 10]), 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Concentration", None}, {"Time", 
    "Concentrations every 10 x units"}}]
Plot[cfun[0.01, x], x ∈ mesh, 
 PlotRange -> {{9, 11}, {0.4, 1.05}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Concentration", None}, {"X", 
    "Concentration near x=10 for small time"}}]
```

[image: Solutions on an anisotropic mesh]

These solutions behave much better than the initial coarse solution and it allows one to resolve a very fine point source without blowing up the model size.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I'm sorry I am new to MMA and FEM. Please excuse me for a few more questions. Could you please explain the legend of the second plot in the post? I would like to know what the green and orange colored solution curves correspond to.

Comment: @Natasha I added some `FrameLabels` and legends for clarity.