# multi-dimensional interpolating function evaluation and extract dimension

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, interpolation, vector

I have an interpolating function which output dimension is greater than 1, so it's a vector. I get it as the result of a NDSolveValue. The problem is that I'm not able to Evaluate it. I would obtain from a single interpolating function which output is a vector a vector containing interpolating function which output is a scalar.
I'll show a simple code:

```
x0 = {1, 3, 6};
eqns = {x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == x0};
t0 = 0;
tfin = 5;
xsol[s_] = NDSolveValue[eqns, x[s], {t, t0, tfin}]
Plot[Evaluate@xsol[t], {t, t0, tfin}]
```

[image]
[image]

```
z[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]};
eqns2 = {z'[t] == -z[t], z[0] == x0};
zsol[s_] = NDSolveValue[eqns2, z[s], {t, t0, tfin}]
Plot[Evaluate@zsol[t], {t, t0, tfin}]
```

[image]
[image]

What to should I do to get from `x[t]` the same result of `z[t]` ? Delaware contain the same information

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Is this correct?  You want to put a value of t into your output expression and get one list of three numbers?

Comment: @Hugh In that way all the two methods work. The fact is that I have a differential equation more complex than this one written in vectorial form, but in this way I'm not able to evaluate the solutions so the program is slower when I apply functions to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed):

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[Indexed[xsol[t], i], {i, 3}], {t, t0, tfin}]
```

[image]

Comment: your solution work pretty well and is what I need. Indexed allow to evaluate the solution in vectorial form. Thank you, have a nice day !

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
x0 = {1, 3, 6};
eqns = {x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == #} &;
t0 = 0;
tfin = 5;
xsol[s_] = NDSolveValue[eqns@#, x[s], {t, t0, tfin}] & /@ x0
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@xsol[t], {t, t0, tfin}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the plot is the main goal, then this is simplest:

```
xsol = NDSolveValue[eqns, x, {t, t0, tfin}] (* N.B. x, not x[s] *)
ListLinePlot@xsol
```

[image]

See also
[Easy way to plot ODE solutions from NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve/134223#134223)

Comment: Thanks, I alredy read it, but I didn't need to plot the solution, just the reorganize them in another form in such way mathematica allows me to evaluate them and speed up further calculations i'm gonna do with them. Thanks ! I've never thought ListLinePlot for these situations

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Table`:

```
With[{x0 = {1, 3, 6}, t0 = 0,tfin = 5}, 
solx[s_] = Table[NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == x0[[i]]}, x[s], 
{t, t0, tfin}], {i, 1, Length[x0]}];
Plot[Evaluate[solx[t]], {t, 0, 5}]]
```

[image: Solutions]