# I want to get the raw data of solutions of partial differential equation in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I have one partial differential equation.

```
sol = NDSolve[{ 
    D[T[x, y, t], {t, 1}] == 
     (D[T[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, y, t], {y, 2}]), 
    T[x, y, 0] == 
     400 - 400 Exp[-100000 x^2 y^2 (x - 1)^2 (y - 1)^2] + 
      350 Exp[-100000 x^2  (x - 1)^2],
    T[x, 0, t] == 350 Exp[-100000 x^2  (x - 1)^2], 
    T[x, 1, t] == 350 Exp[-100000 x^2  (x - 1)^2], T[0, y, t] == 350, 
    T[1, y, t] == 350}, {T[x, y, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 
    100}, PrecisionGoal -> 2];
```

This sol is an `InterpolationgFunctiion`. I want to get the raw numerical data from this `InterpolatingFunction`.

Do I use `InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid` or `InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates`, I don't understand these tools.

How do I extract data from above function?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
sol = T/.NDSolve[{D[T[x,y,t], {t,1}]==(D[T[x,y,t], {x,2}] + D[T[x,y,t], {y,2}]), 
  T[x,y,0]==400-400 Exp[-100000 x^2 y^2(x-1)^2 (y-1)^2]+ 350 Exp[-100000 x^2 (x-1)^2], 
  T[x,0,t]==350 Exp[-100000 x^2 (x-1)^2], 
  T[x,1,t]==350 Exp[-100000 x^2 (x-1)^2],
  T[0,y,t]==350,
  T[1,y,t]==350},
  T, {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}, {t,0,100}, PrecisionGoal->2][[1]];
InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[sol]
```

The output is large enough that it shows a shortened version. You can then click on show more (repeatedly) or click on show all and wait..... for it.

That should show you a large grid of result values.

You can assign that grid of values to a variable and use subscripting to extract individual items.

Comment: Alternatively, `sol["ValuesOnGrid"]`

Comment: What does [[1]] mean?

Comment: @Shakariky Click here -> https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html

Comment: What does T/. mean? Sorry.

Comment: @Shak, whenever you encounter an unfamiliar symbol in *Mathematica*, just highlight it and press F1.

Answer (score 0):

[Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18890/bill) and [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) has already answered OP's question, but after some communication with OP in the comment under [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111178/1871), I think it's worth explaining the usage of `InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[sol]` / `sol["ValuesOnGrid"]` and `InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[sol]` / `sol["Coordinates"]` a bit further.

As the function names suggest, `sol["ValuesOnGrid"]` is a list of the function value on the grid. (For OP's case, it's a list of value of $T$.) `sol["Coordinates"]` is a list of the coordinate of grid. (For OP's case, it's a list of value of $x$,$y$,$t$.) If you want to build a list of $(x,y,t,T)$ that can be used in e.g. `ListDensityPlot3D`, you can:

```
sol = T /. First@
    NDSolve[{D[T[x, y, t], {t, 1}] == (D[T[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, y, t], {y, 2}]), 
      T[x, y, 0] == 
       400 - 400 Exp[-100000 x^2 y^2 (x - 1)^2 (y - 1)^2] + 
        350 Exp[-100000 x^2 (x - 1)^2], T[x, 0, t] == 350 Exp[-100000 x^2 (x - 1)^2], 
      T[x, 1, t] == 350 Exp[-100000 x^2 (x - 1)^2], T[0, y, t] == 350, 
      T[1, y, t] == 350}, T, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}, PrecisionGoal -> 2];

lstT = sol["ValuesOnGrid"];
lstxyt = {lstx, lsty, lstt} = sol["Coordinates"];
{lenx, leny, lent} = Dimensions@lstT;

(* solution 1, not that fast but easy to understand *)
lstxytT = Table[{lstx[[i]], lsty[[j]], lstt[[k]], lstT[[i, j, k]]}, 
                {i, lenx}, {j, leny}, {k, lent}];

(* solution 2, a bit harder to understand but fast *)
lstxytT2 = Transpose[{Transpose[ConstantArray[lstx, {leny, lent}], {2, 3, 1}], 
                      Transpose[ConstantArray[lsty, {lenx, lent}], {1, 3, 2}], 
                                ConstantArray[lstt, {lenx, leny}], 
                                              lstT}, 
                     {4, 1, 2, 3}];

lstxytT == lstxytT2
(* True *)

ListDensityPlot3D@lstxytT
(* I'm still in v9 so let me omit the picture here *)
```

Finally I'd like to mention that `lstT` and `lstxyt` can be directly used for the building of a interpolating function of $T(x,y,t)$:

```
solsimpler = ListInterpolation[lstT, lstxyt]
```

Notice `solsimpler` isn't the same as `sol` because it's only built with `"ValuesOnGrid"` and `"Coordinates"`. To learn more about the information contained in `InterpolatingFunction`, check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871) post.