# How do you obtain the limits of the domain of an interpolated function?

Tags: interpolation

I am dealing with a very large number of tables that I interpolate over. It would be easiest if I did not have to go back to the original table to obtain the limits of the domain of interpolation, and instead work with the interpolated function itself. For some interpolation function NEWFOOINT:

```
 In[661]:= NEWFOOINT

  Out[661]= InterpolatingFunction[{{-31.68291818753900559397937565, 
   -3.249352757300243415151413968}}, <>]
```

How does one return the values -31.68291818753900559397937565 and -3.249352757300243415151413968 aside from visual inspection?

Thank you!

Comment: `NEWFOOINT["Domain"]`, but it's undocumented. But, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043).