# Using EventLocator to detect periodic solutions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, periodic-function, event-detection

I loop over some systems of DAEs with `NDSolve`; some solutions are periodic, some are not. When integrating with `NDSolve`, I integrate on `{t,-1000,1000}` starting from `t=0` because I don't want to compute only one part of the non-periodic solutions. The problem is that when orbits are periodic, it computes the solution on several periods. To avoid this, I used `EventLocator` with the following testing function:

```
 isPeriodic[vals_, ic_] := (Norm[vals - ic] < .02) && (t < -1 || t > 1)
```

The `0.02` instead of `0` is due to numerical inaccuracies which makes the solution not perfectly periodic, but "almost". The condition `t < -1 || t > 1` is used to prevent `NDSolve` from stopping immediately after starting ($f(0.000001)$ and $f(0)$ would trigger the periodicity condition since $\|f(0.000001)-f(0)\|$ is very likely to be lower than $0.02$).

This works pretty well, except that I it returns the solution over two periods: $f(t)==f(0)$ is checked both for positive *and* negative `t`.

I could of course split the interval in two and keep only one part, but for some reasons I'd prefer to avoid that; additionally, it would avoid computing the periodic solution on two periods.

Full code, which may seem sligthly complex but is not really:

```
(* defines variables and system of DAE *)
vars = Array[s, 2];
varst = Through[vars[t]];
ic = {56.30672012303853`, 1.9416110387254666`};
sysDAE0 = {{0.2763932022500211` Sin[
        0.8090169943749473` (-s[1][t] + s[2][t])] Sin[
        0.3090169943749473` (s[1][t] + s[2][t])] + 
      0.7236067977499788` Sin[
        0.3090169943749473` (-s[1][t] + s[2][t])] Sin[
        0.8090169943749473` (s[1][t] + s[2][t])]} == {0}, 
   Derivative[1][s[1]][t]^2 + Derivative[1][s[2]][t]^2 == 
    1.`, {s[1][0], s[2][0]} == 
    ic, {Derivative[1][s[1]][0], 
     Derivative[1][s[2]][0]} == {-0.8903443552034469`, 
     0.45528774325404187`}};

(* test of periodicity *)    
isPeriodic[vals_, 
  ci_] := (Norm[vals - ci] < .02) && (t < -1 || t > 1)

(* solves the system *)
{solDAE} = 
 NDSolve[sysDAE0, vars, {t, -1000, 1000}, 
  Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> isPeriodic[varst, ic],
                         "EventAction" :> Throw[Null, "StopIntegration"]}]
sol[t_] := Through[(vars /. solDAE)[t]];
{tmin, tmax} = Flatten@solDAE[[1]][[2, 1]];
```

And the output, which is a closed curve (periodicity) plotted twice:

```
ParametricPlot[sol[t], {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

[image]

**Question** How to use events to compute only one period of the solution? One possibility would be to stop integration in both positive and negative `t` when the first periodicity condition is found, but `"StopIntegration"` does not do that (luckily).

Another possibility is to introduce a boolean `boolPeriodic`, turning it to `True` when the first periodic event is detected, and adding this boolean as an event to kill immediately the integration in the other direction (hence, avoiding computing a second time the period). But it does not help: it seems the `EventLocator` method is run in parallel for positive `t` and negative `t`. This is confirmed by adding a `Print` in the `EventAction`:

```
boolPeriodic = False; {solDAE} = 
 NDSolve[sysDAE0, vars, {t, -1000, 1000}, 
  Method -> {"EventLocator", 
    "Event" -> isPeriodic[varst, ic] || boolPeriodic, 
    "EventAction" :> Throw[boolPeriodic = True;Print["periodic"], "StopIntegration"]}]
sol[t_] := Through[(vars /. solDAE)[t]];

(* prints TWO "periodic" *)
```

Comment: `WhenEvent[]` superseded `"EventLocator" in V9 -- what version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm using V11; I tried `WhenEvent[]` but did not manage to make it work. I'm going to add the code I tried (but I don't think it will change something).

Comment: Doesn't your code compute one orbit in each direction?  If you integrate `{t, 0, 1000}` (or `{t, 0 Infinity}`), won't that give you what you want?

Comment: To clarify, integration always starts from the initial condition (`t == 0` in this case). So the forward integration `0 < t < 1000` captures one period and the backward integration `0 > t > -1000` get another period.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's exactly the issue. I clarified the question and also explained why I can't just integrate over `{t, 0, 1000}`.

Comment: I guess you could integrate a little to into negative `t`, say, `{t, -0.1, 0}`, with one `NDSolve` call,  and use the values of `vars` at `t == -0.1` to construct the stopping criterion for a second `NDSolve` call over `{t, -1000, 1000}`.  I don't think the initial condition can be an "event."

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's a possibility, but then I would have to [splice the interpolating function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction). I answered with a solution which is not perfect, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way, stopping the forward integration if the backward integration is found to be periodic:

```
(*solves the system*)
periodicQ = False;
{solDAE} = NDSolve[{sysDAE0,
   WhenEvent[Evaluate@isPeriodic[varst, ic],
    periodicQ = True; "StopIntegration"],
   WhenEvent[Positive[t] && periodicQ,         (* was  t > $MachineEpsilon && periodicQ *) 
    "StopIntegration", "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]},
  vars, {t, -1000, 1000}]
sol[t_] := Through[(vars /. solDAE)[t]];
{tmin, tmax} = Flatten@solDAE[[1]][[2, 1]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[sol[t], {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update note:* 
First note that `NDSolve` integrates backwards from the initial condition to the beginning of the integration interval, if necessary, and next integrates forward from the IC to the end of the interval, if necessary.  The event to stop forward integration in the case where a periodic solution was found in the backward integration was `t > $MachineEpsilon`, with an action to stop integration at the beginning of the step.  I imagine it is extremely rare that the initial step in the forward integration would be less than `$MachineEpsilon`, but it's possible.  Perhaps `$MinMachineNumber` is better.  What would seem more exactly right is `t > 0`, but this is a special case in [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html).  It means that `t` changes from negative to positive. Since integration starts at `t == 0`, this event does not happen.  However, `Positive[t]` is not a special case.  It changes from `False` to `True` at the first step and so triggers an event.  In general one might use `Positive[t - t0]` for an initial condition at `t == t0`.

---

Addendum: One can turn the solution into a periodic function, using the option `PeriodicInterpolation` and massaging the solution a little.

First I would change `isPeriodic[]` to be a little more accurate:

```
isPeriodic[vals_, ci_] := First[vals] == First[ci] && (Norm[vals - ci] < .02);
```

Then if you re-excute the code for `solDAE` we get much closer to an exact period:

```
{#["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, -1}]], 
   Derivative[1][#]["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, -1}]]} & /@ (vars /. solDAE)
(*
  {{{56.3067, 56.3067}, {-0.890345, -0.890344}},   <-- s[1]
   {{1.94161, 1.94161}, {0.455287, 0.455288}}}     <-- s[2]
*)
```

For `PeriodicInterpolation` to work, the first and last values have to be identical.  They are close enough to replace the last one with the first one.  The point `t == 0.` is also duplicated, because of the event stopping the forward integration. We need to delete it (with `Most`).

```
periodify[list_List] := ReplacePart[list, -1 -> First@list];

ClearAll[sol2];
sol2[t_] = Interpolation[Transpose@{
       Most@ #["Grid"],
       periodify@ Most@ #["ValuesOnGrid"],
       periodify@ Most@ Derivative[1][#]["ValuesOnGrid"]}, 
     PeriodicInterpolation -> True][t] & /@ (vars /. solDAE);
```

Here is a plot over several periods:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Flatten@{t, sol2[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, BoxRatios -> {1/2, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It seems doing so introduces a "bug" when exporting and importing back?! I am writing a question about this, I'll post the link here.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130791/strange-behaviour-after-importing-exported-interpolatingfunction

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution, but this does the trick:

```
(*solves the system*)
periodic = False;
{solDAE} = NDSolve[sysDAE0~Join~{WhenEvent[Evaluate@isPeriodic[varst, ic], 
           periodic = True; "StopIntegration"]}, vars, {t, -1000, 1000}]
sol[t_] := Through[(vars /. solDAE)[t]];
{tmin, tmax} = If[periodique==True,
             {0,sol["Domain"[]][[1,1,2]]},sol["Domain"[]][[1,1]]]
```

First, the code is rewritten with `WhenEvent` instead of the obsolete`EventLocator` (cf Michael E2's comment). It introduces a boolean `periodic`; when the periodic event is detected, it triggers `"StopIntegration"` and also sets `periodic` to `True`.  Then, it suffices to select half of the domain if the solution is periodic, and all of it otherwise. A last step would be to redefine the interpolating function on the right domain (instead of just saving the extremal values of it's parameter into two variables), but I don't know how to that yet.