# Importing an InterpolatingFunction computed with option "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"

Tags: bugs, export, import, interpolation

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.1**

---

*Apparent bug observed in MMA 11.0.0.0.*

2016/11/10 Wolfram Support Team contacted.

2016//11/29 Passed along the report to developers for further diagnosis

---

The following code is just to generate the `InterpolatingFunction` of interest:

```
isPeriodic[vals_, ic_] := (Norm[vals - ic] < .02) && (t < -1 || t > 1)
vars = Array[s, 2];
varst = Through[vars[t]];
ic = {56.30672012303853`, 1.9416110387254666`};
sysDAE0 = {{0.2763932022500211` Sin[0.8090169943749473` (-s[1][t] + s[2][t])] Sin[
        0.3090169943749473` (s[1][t] + s[2][t])] + 0.7236067977499788` Sin[0.3090169943749473` (-s[1][t] + s[2][t])] 
Sin[0.8090169943749473` (s[1][t] + s[2][t])]} == {0}, 
   Derivative[1][s[1]][t]^2 + Derivative[1][s[2]][t]^2 == 1.`, {s[1][0], s[2][0]} == ic,
 {Derivative[1][s[1]][0], Derivative[1][s[2]][0]} == {-0.8903443552034469`, 
     0.45528774325404187`}};
isPeriodic[vals_, ci_] := (Norm[vals - ci] < .02) && (t < -1 || t > 1)
(*solves the system*)periodicQ = False;
{solDAE} = NDSolve[{sysDAE0, 
   WhenEvent[Evaluate@isPeriodic[varst, ic], periodicQ = True; "StopIntegration"], 
   WhenEvent[Positive[t] && periodicQ,"StopIntegration", "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]}, 
vars, {t, -1000, 1000}]
sol[t_] := Through[(vars /. solDAE)[t]];
{tmin, tmax} = Flatten@solDAE[[1]][[2, 1]];
```

That works perfectly well, and `sol[t]` returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, if I save `sol[t]` and import it back:

```
Export["temp.m", sol[t]]
sol2 = Import["temp.m"]
```

returns the `InputForm` of the function, instead of the nice compact one (`StandardForm`):

```
{InterpolatingFunction[{{-13.8905, 0.}}, {5, 3, 1, {583}, {4}, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, 
   False}, {{-13.8905, -13.8543, -13.8179, -13.7815, -13.7452, \
-13.7088, -13.6724, -13.636, -13.5997, -13.5633, -13.5269, -13.4905, \
-13.4724, -13.4542, -13.436, -13.4178, -13.3996, -13.3814, -13.3632, \
-13.345, -13.3269, -13.3063, -13.2858, -13.2652, -13.2447, -13.2241, \
-13.2036, -13.1808, -13.1579, -13.1326, -13.1072, -13.0819, -13.0565, \
...
```

Note that **without** `WhenEvent[Positive[t] && periodicQ,"StopIntegration", "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]`, the `Import` works perfectly: it gives the `InterpolatingFunction`s in the nice form.

What is happening and how to solve this issue?

**Edit** It appears to be somehow related to `"LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"`: when removed, the importation works well. But I don't see the point.

Comment: That's a bug - please report this to Wolfram (support AT wolfram.com).

Comment: @user21 Done. Side question: how can you be _sure_ it's a bug? Of course, I find it strange too, but some other things I found strange sometimes appeared to come from my misunderstandings.

Comment: The fact the the re-imported `InterpolatingFunction` did not evaluate to it's data structure `InterpolatinngFunction[<..>]` suggests that it did not evaluate; and that's a bug. In principal one could write by hand the content of an `InteprolatingFunction[]` ( in theory) and there has to be an internal check that whatever is entered is actually a valid `InterpolationFunction` data structure - that check, my guess, did not like something when it got re-inported and rejected the data structure to be a valid `InterplatingFunction` data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received an email from Wolfram Technical Support mentioning that this bug *has been resolved in the current 11.1.1 release of Mathematica*.

That'd be perfect if someone could confirm.

Comment: I reproduced the bug with versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.1. With version 11.1.1 there is no bug.