# Make an InterpolatingFunction periodic

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

`Interpolation` can make an `InterpolatingFunction` periodic with the option `PeriodicInterpolation`.  Can we make an `InterpolatingFunction` that already exists periodic, perhaps the output of `NDSolve`?

For example, this predator-prey model has the following limit cycle:

```
per = 11.961276218870646`;
sol = NDSolve[{
  n'[t] == (1 - n[t]/3.5) n[t] - (n[t] p[t])/(1 + n[t]), 
  p'[t] == (-1 + (2 n[t])/(1 + n[t])) p[t],
  n[0] == 2.356251381534703`, p[0] == 1.1409965294442128`},
  {n, p}, {t, 0, per}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{n[t], p[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, per}]
```

[image]

Comment: Here's another approach: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130064/4999

Comment: That seems... safer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll add another method and the method from my comment in an answer.

My usual way has been a workaround instead of constructing a new interpolating function; this is similar to @m_goldberg's solution:

```
pN1 = With[{ifn = n /. sol},
  With[{dom = Flatten@ifn["Domain"]},
   Evaluate@ifn[Mod[#, -Subtract @@ dom, First@dom]] &
   ]]
```

From [Using EventLocator to detect periodic solutions in NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129993/using-eventlocator-to-detect-periodic-solutions-in-ndsolve/130064#130064), adding the second derivative to help smooth out the interpolation a little:

```
periodify[list_List] := Append[list, First@list];
pN2 = Interpolation[
    Transpose@{#["Grid"], 
      periodify@Most@#["ValuesOnGrid"], 
      periodify@Most@Derivative[1][#]["ValuesOnGrid"],
      periodify@Most@Derivative[2][#]["ValuesOnGrid"]}, 
    PeriodicInterpolation -> True] &[n /. sol]
```

[image]
[image]

The singularity in the second derivative is found in @ChrisK's solution, too. In fact, there seems to be no difference in computed values between Chris's solution and `pN2[x]`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if we're willing to risk modifying the internals of the `InterpolatingFunction`.  Using info from [this answer from MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152861) and some guesswork, it looks like we need to change three things in the `InterpolatingFunction`:

1. set the periodic flag in part {2, 7} to {1}
2. decrease the ngrid in part {2, 4} by 1
3. remove the last data point in part {4}

There are lots of possible versions and methods in the `InterpolatingFunction`.  The following works for two one-dimensional cases, on version-5 (part {2, 1}) `InterpolatingFunctions`:

```
MakeInterpolatingFunctionPeriodic[if_InterpolatingFunction]:=Module[{
    dorder=if[[2,3]],
    ngrid=if[[2,4]]},
    Which[
        if[[4,1]]===Developer`PackedArrayForm,
        ReplacePart[if,{
            {2,7}->{1}, (* set periodic flag *)
            {2,4}->ngrid-1 ,(* decrease ngrid by 1 *)
            {4,2}->Drop[if[[4,2]],-1], (* remove last abscissa *)
            {4,3}->Drop[if[[4,3]],-dorder-1] (* remove last dorder+1 values *)
        }]
    ,
        ListQ[if[[4,1]]],
        ReplacePart[if,{
            {2,7}->{1}, (* set periodic flag *)
            {2,4}->ngrid-1, (* decrease ngrid by 1 *)
            {4}->Drop[if[[4]],-1] (* remove last point *)
        }]
    ]
];
```

Testing it out on the `NDSolve` output from the question:

```
n /. sol
MakeInterpolatingFunctionPeriodic[n /. sol]
```

[image]
[image]

```
Plot[n[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 24}]
Plot[MakeInterpolatingFunctionPeriodic[n /. sol][t], {t, 0, 24}]
```

[image]
[image]

Use at your own peril, since the internals of `InterpolatingFunction` might change and I've only covered two cases.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without modifying `InterpolatingFunction`. Like so:

```
{perNF, perPF} =
   Module[{per, lo, hi, n0, p0, nF, pF, k},
     per = Rationalize[11.961276218870646`, 0];
     lo = 0;
     hi = lo + per;
     n0 = Rationalize[2.356251381534703`, 0];
     p0 = Rationalize[1.1409965294442128`, 0];
     {nF, pF} =
       NDSolveValue[
         {n'[t] == (1 - n[t]/(7/2)) n[t] - (n[t] p[t])/(1 + n[t]), 
          p'[t] == (-1 + (2 n[t])/(1 + n[t])) p[t],
          n[0] == n0, p[0] == p0},
         {n, p}, {t, lo, hi}];
     Function[f,
       With[{u = Rationalize[#, 0]},
         Which[
           u < lo,
           k = Solve[lo ≤ u + n per ≤ hi, n, Integers][[1, 1, 2]];
           f[u + k per],
           u > hi,
           k = Solve[lo ≤ u - n per ≤ hi, n, Integers][[1, 1, 2]];
           f[u - k per],
           True, f[u]]] &] /@ {nF, pF}];
```

Then

```
With[{per = 11.961276218870646`}, Plot[{{perNF[t], perPF[t]}}, {t, 0, per}]]
```

[image: plot_1]

recovers the plot posted in the question, and

```
With[{per = 11.961276218870646`}, Plot[{{perNF[t], perPF[t]}}, {t, -per, 3 per}]]
```

[image: plot_2]

plots the two solutions of the system of ODEs over four periods.