# Piecewise[ ] for joining InterpolationFunction objects?

Tags: interpolation, piecewise, debugging

I want to combine InterpolationFunction objects, results of an NDSolve in a loop, into one function. This is my code:

```
k1 = 3; sin = 2; \[Alpha] = 0.5;

\[Mu][s_, t_] := (0.35)*s[t]/(0.7 + s[t] + ((s[t])^2)*(0.6) );  

um = 0.097032;
up = 0.2093;

k2 = 5.6;
\[Beta] = 0.33;
\[Tau] = 3;

s0 = 0.1;
x0 = 0.2;

steps = 65;

PiecesX = {};
PiecesS = {};
Conditions = {};
Starts = {{s0, x0}};

For[i = 1, i <= Ceiling[steps/\[Tau]], i++,
  s0 = Starts[[i]][[1]];
  x0 = Starts[[i]][[2]];
  u = um;
  te = (i - 1)*\[Tau];
  \[Omega] = Floor[te/\[Tau]]*\[Tau];
  k = \[Beta]*k2*\[Mu][ssol, \[Omega]]*xsol[\[Omega]];
  If[k > um && k < up, u = k];
  If[k >= up, u = up];
  {ssol, xsol} = 
   NDSolveValue[{s'[t] == -k1*\[Mu][s, t]*x[t] + u*(sin - s[t]),
                            x'[t] == (\[Mu][s, t] - \[Alpha]*u)*x[t],
                            s[(i - 1)*\[Tau]] == s0, x[(i - 1)*\[Tau]] == x0},
                             {s, x}, {t, (i - 1)*\[Tau], i*\[Tau]}]; 
  AppendTo[PiecesS, ssol];
  AppendTo[PiecesX, xsol];
  AppendTo[Conditions, (i - 1)*\[Tau] < t < i*\[Tau]];
  AppendTo[Starts, {ssol[i*\[Tau]], xsol[i*\[Tau]]}];
  ];

 
solX = Piecewise[Transpose[{PiecesX, Conditions}]];
solS = Piecewise[Transpose[{PiecesS, Conditions}]];
```

The functions solX and solS look like normal piecewise functions in output, but refuse to be plotted. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you fix the incorrect syntax? 1) This is incorrect `[Mu]` - it should be `\[Mu]`, same for Alpha and Tau if you meant the symbols.  2) `sin` is wrong. It should be `Sin`. Also there are loads of things you haven't given us here like the values of mu, alpha, s0, x0, u ... etc How do you expect anybody to run your code without them?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am new to this, so I tought I had an obvious mistake, didnt want to make it heavy with constants sorry

Comment: That now seems to work fine for me: `Plot[solX[t], {t, 0, 66}]` produces a curve.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction