# Crank-Nicolson solver for heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

My ultimate goal is to solve the 1D radial diffusion equation

$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x}=x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{D(t)}{x^2} \frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x } \right)$$ with a time-dependent diffusion coefficient $D(t)$, but as a first step I want to solve the simple 1D diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x}=D\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial x^2}$$

with a constant diffusion coefficient $D$ (`K` in code), which I'll set equal to `1`.

The initial condition is
$$u(0,x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi L_t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{L_t^2}}$$
and here I also set the scale parameter $L_t=1$ (`Lt = 1` in code) for now.

The boundary conditions are
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
{u(t,-10)=0\\
u(t,10)=0}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

I want to use a Crank-Nicolson solver and I've used the code given [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html).

I've done some small adjustments, for example added an option for the `MaxStepSize` and my complete code reads as follows. For solving the equation I've adapted the example given (behind the same link) for solving the wave equation.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(*Define options and method initialization for the Crank–Nicolson*)

Options[CrankNicolson] = {MaxIterations -> 10, Tolerance -> Automatic,
    MaxStepSize -> Automatic};
CrankNicolson /: 
 NDSolve`InitializeMethod[CrankNicolson, stepmode_, sd_, rhs_, state_,
   OptionsPattern[CrankNicolson]] := 
 Module[{prec, rtol, maxit}, maxit = OptionValue[MaxIterations];
  prec = state@"WorkingPrecision";
  rtol = OptionValue[Tolerance];
  If[rtol === Automatic, rtol = 10^(-prec*3/4)];
  CrankNicolson[maxit, rtol]]

(*Define the step function:*)

CrankNicolson[maxit_, rtol_]["Step"[f_, h_, t0_, x0_, f0_]] := 
  Module[{J, LU, t1 = t0 + h, x1, f1, residual, err, done = False, 
    tol = rtol, count = 0},
   x1 = x0 + h f0;
   f1 = f[t1, x1];
   x1 = x0 + (h/2) (f0 + f1);
   J = f["JacobianMatrix"[t1, x1]];
   LU = IdentityMatrix[Length[x1], SparseArray] - (h/2) J;
   LU = LinearSolve[LU];
   While[(count <= maxit) && ! done, f1 = f[t1, x1];
    residual = x1 - x0 - (h/2)*(f0 + f1);
    err = Norm[residual, Infinity];
    If[err < tol, done = True
     (*else*), x1 = x1 - LU[residual];
     count++;
     ]
    ];
   If[count > maxit, Message[CrankNicolson::cvmit, maxit];
    x1 = $Failed];
   {x1, f1}
   ];

(*This specifies for NDSolve the inputs, outputs, difference order, and 
  step mode for the Crank–Nicolson method:*)

CrankNicolson[___]["StepInput"] = {"F"["T", "X"], "H", "T", "X", "XP"};
CrankNicolson[___]["StepOutput"] = {"X", "XP"};
CrankNicolson[___]["DifferenceOrder"] := 2;
CrankNicolson[___]["StepMode"] := "Fixed";

(*Model paramaters*)
K = 1;
Lt = 1;
tmax = 10^2;
msf = 0.001;
k = 0.01;
xlim = 10;

(*Run the solver*)
uF = First[
   u /. NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == K*D[u[t, x], x, x], 
      u[0, x] == Sqrt[2/(Pi*Lt)]*Exp[-x^2/Lt^2], u[t, -xlim] == 0, 
      u[t, xlim] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1*tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
     Method -> {"DoubleStep", 
       Method -> {CrankNicolson, 
         MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 10^-7}}}]];

(*Plot results in 2D*)
Plot3D[
 Evaluate[uF[t, x]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All]
```

I now have two problems. First, the distribution should approach a uniform one in the spatial dimension as $t \rightarrow \infty$. However, when I look at the plot given by the code, the distribution seems to approach zero. I don't understand this, since in the diffusion equation I have no loss term, so the integral over $x$ should be constant, if I'm, not mistaken. However, this isn't the case right now. I've tried to decrease the `MaxStepSize` down to `10^-8` in both dimensions, but the result doesn't seem to change or the computation aborts. Below is the resulting graph I get, but I think that the "plateu" should be higher, approaching about `0.07` from above to conserve the spatial integral.
[image: Solution of the 1D heat equation.]

A second problem is that when I set `tmax = 600` or larger, the solution starts to show a distribution that looks really strange, and setting `tmax = 10^4` the behavior is clearly visible.[image]

Comment: So, you know the default setting of `NDSolve` can handle the problem without difficulty, but you just want to use Crank-Nicolson, right?

Comment: I actually tried NDSolveValue too with automatic algorithm selection, but there my first problem still emerged, so I didn't get the built-in settings to do the job either. In any case, yes, I want to use Crank-Nicolson, but would also appreciate guidance in using the standard settings of NDSolveValue.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: "First, the distribution should approach a uniform one in the spatial dimension as t→∞. However, …, the distribution seems to approach zero.  I don't understand this, since in the diffusion equation I have no loss term, so the integral over x should be constant, if I'm, not mistaken. " Sadly, you're mistaken. Indeed, there's no loss term **inside** the PDE, but you set Dirichlet b.c. `u[t, -xlim] == 0, u[t, xlim] == 0` This is amount to cooling down the whole domain with 2 walls whose temperatures are `0`. You need to set adiabatic boundary condition i.e. Neumann b.c. whose RHS is `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much xzczd, that makes sense. I'm more than happy to be mistaken here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to an answer. 3 issues here.

### **1. The boundary conditions are incorrect**

> … the distribution seems to approach zero. I don't understand this, since in the diffusion equation I have no loss term, so the integral over x should be constant, if I'm, not mistaken. "

Sadly, you're mistaken. Indeed, there's no loss term **inside** the PDE, but you've set Dirichlet b.c. `u[t, -xlim] == 0, u[t, xlim] == 0`. This is amount to cooling down the whole domain with 2 walls whose temperatures are `0`. You need to set adiabatic boundary condition i.e. Neumann b.c. whose RHS is `0`:

```
K = 1;
Lt = 1;
tmax = 10^2;
msf = 0.001;
k = 0.01;
xlim = 10;

eq = D[u[t, x], t] == K*D[u[t, x], x, x];
ic = u[0, x] == Sqrt[2/(Pi*Lt)]*Exp[-x^2/Lt^2];
bc = D[u[t, x], x] == 0 /. {{x -> -xlim}, {x -> xlim}}

uFref = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1*tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0242869, Null} *)

Animate[Plot[uFref[t, x], {x, -xlim, xlim}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.8}], {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

As we can see, now the "plateu" approaches about `0.07` as expected.

You can use `CrankNicolson` of course. The result looks the same, and the corresponding timing is about `0.117249` second. I'm not sure why you need Crank-Nicolson, but do remember the default ODE solver of `NDSolve` is quite robust and efficient, if it fails to solve a problem, classical method like RK4, Crank-Nicolson, etc. probably won't help either. ODE solver of `NDSolve` should always be the last thing to adjust.

### **2. The `MaxStepSize` doesn't have any effect**

> I've done some small adjustments, for example added an option for the `MaxStepSize`…

But this `MaxStepSize` in `Options[CrankNicolson]` is meaningless. Just try:

```
uF1 = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
   Method -> {DoubleStep, 
     Method -> {CrankNicolson, MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 10^-7}}}];

uF2 = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
   Method -> {DoubleStep, Method -> {CrankNicolson, MaxStepSize -> ahhhhhh}}];

uF1 === uF2
(* True *)
```

Why? Because you've misunderstood how the `Option` of a function works. I know beginners may guess that, once `Options[f]={…}` is set, the function `f` will be clever enough to use those options in certain miraculous way, but it's not true. If you read the source code of `CrankNicolson` carefully, you'll see the option values of `MaxIterations` and `Tolerance` are explicitly refered with `OptionValue`!

"OK, then what's the correct way to set `MaxStepSize` for `CrankNicolson`?" There doesn't seem to be a simple way, because step size control isn't coded in the refered `CrankNicolson`, but `MaxStepSize` is already an option of `NDSolve`, why not use it? For example:

```
uF = 
  NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
   MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 2 xlim/200}, 
   Method -> {DoubleStep, Method -> {CrankNicolson}}];

Dimensions /@ uF["Coordinates"]
(* {{30}, {201}} *)
```

I've used the undocumented `"Coordinates"` argument to extract grid coordinates from `InterpolatingFunction[…]`. To learn more about extracting data from `InterpolatingFunction[…]`, check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871) post.

### **3. `StiffnessTest` should be turned off**

Now, if you try `CrankNicolson` with `tmax = 10^4`, you'll see

> `NDSolveValue::ndstf` At t == 111.35824722214431`, system appears to be stiff. Methods Automatic, BDF, or StiffnessSwitching may be more appropriate.

Observing the solution around `t == 111`, it doesn't seem to be stiff, so the stiffness detector of `DoubleStep` hasn't done a good job here. Then how to fix? I know little about stiffness detection, but according to my limited knowledge, Crank-Nicolson, which is an implicit method, doesn't need it, so let's turn it off:

```
tmax = 10^4; 
uFlong = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
  Method -> {DoubleStep, Method -> {CrankNicolson, MaxIterations -> 40}, 
    StiffnessTest -> False}];
```

Alternatively we can build this into `CrankNicolson`. Just execute

```
CrankNicolson[___]["StiffMethodQ"] := True;
```

The usage of `"StiffMethodQ"` is mentioned in tutorial ["DoubleStep" Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDoubleStep.html). Now we don't need `StiffnessTest` option:

```
tmax = 10^4; 
uFlong2 = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xlim, xlim}, 
  Method -> {DoubleStep, 
             Method -> {CrankNicolson, MaxIterations -> 40}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.92179, Null} *)
```

For comparison, timing of default method is `0.0297851` second.