# What do the arguments of a generated BSplineFunction mean?

Tags: implementation-details, undocumented, splines, internals

For example, if we evaluate this:

```
BSplineFunction@{{0,100},{200,50},{200,0}}
```

we'll get

```
BSplineFunction[1,
    {{0., 1.}},
    {2}, {False}, {{{0., 100.}, {200., 50.}, {200., 0.}}, Automatic},
    {{0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.}},
    {0}, MachinePrecision, "Unevaluated"
]
```

What do these mean?

Answer (score 11):

Mimicking the spelunking in

[How to splice together several instances of InterpolatingFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/1871)

We find

```
func = BSplineFunction[{{0, 100}, {200, 50}, {200, 0}, {300, 0}}];
lst = func@Methods
(* {"Closed", "ControlPoints", "Degree", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", 
    "Evaluate", "ExtrapolationMethod", "Knots", "MethodInformation", 
    "Methods", "Properties", "Rank", "Weights", "WorkingPrecision"} *)

func@MethodInformation@# & /@ lst;
```

> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Closed
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Closed[]` returns the closedness of the
> B-spline function in each dimension.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`ControlPoints
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@ControlPoints` gives the control points.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Degree
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Degree[]` returns the polynomial degree
> of the B-spline function in each dimension.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`DerivativeOrder
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@DerivativeOrder[]` returns what
> derivative of the B-spline function will be computed upon evaluation.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Domain
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Domain[]` returns the domain inteval in
> each direction.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Evaluate
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Evaluate[arg]` evaluates the B-spline
> function at the argument arg.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`ExtrapolationMethod
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@ExtrapolationMethod` returns what type of
> extrapolation method will be used upon evaulation outside the domain.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Knots
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Knots[]` returns the knot sequence in
> each dimension.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`MethodInformation
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@MethodInformation[method]` gives
> information about a particular method.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Methods
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Methods[pat]` gives the list of methods
> matching the string pattern `pat`.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Properties
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Properties` gives the list of possible
> properties.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Rank
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Rank` gives the rank of the B-spline
> function domain.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`Weights
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@Weights` gives the weights associated
> with the control points.
>
> ```
> System`BSplineFunction`WorkingPrecision
> ```
>
> `BSplineFunction[domain, data]@WorkingPrecision` returns what working
> precision will be used during the computation.

It's worth pointing out that, the `ExtrapolationMethod` method doesn't have any effect at least in *v13.2*.

With these info, I can figure out the meaning of `Most` of the arguments:

```
BSplineFunction[Rank, Domain, Degree, Closed, 
                {ControlPoints, Weights}, Knots, DerivativeOrder, 
                WorkingPrecision, ???]
```

Yeah, I don't know what `"Unevaluated"` means. Seems that even if it's changed to anything else, it'll simply be ignored. (If I have to guess, it might be a position for the unfinished `ExtrapolationMethod`? )

BTW, it's worth mentioning that, even if the `Domain` is changed to anything else, it's simply ignored. I guess there're more, but it's time to go to bed now.

Answer (score 10):

This is the full internal representation of `BSplineFunction` with all relevant parameters. You can fiddle around with the options, then open the information box and compare the values to find the correspondence.

```
pts = {{0, 100}, {200, 50}, {200, 0}, {300, 50}};
BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True]
% // InputForm
```

[image]

The syntax is therefore:

```
BSplineFunction[Rank, ?, SplineDegree, SplineClosed,
  {ControlPoints, SplineWeights}, SplineKnots, ?, WorkingPrecision, "Unevaluated"]
```

I don't know what the second argument means (it seems to always be a list with rank repeats of `{0., 1.}`), and the last argument seems to always be `"Unevaluated"`. It looks like changing any of them doesn't affect the spline. There is also an argument before `WorkingPrecision` which I was unable to identify – it corresponds to `DerivativeOrder` as shown in xzczd's answer.

Comment: You've missed the argument before `WorkingPrecision` :) .

Comment: Oh, right, missed that one :)