# Faster position-based duplicate removal in a ragged array?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Take a ragged 2D array:

```
rArray={{4, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 0}, {3, 4}}
```

I need to "deduplicate" this, where a duplicate is any element of a sublist where that element exists at the same position in a prior sublist, e.g., on the above example, the result would be

> {{4, 2, 1, 0}, {2}, {0, 0, 3, 3, 3}, {}, {3, 4}}

Targets are numeric (integer, in fact).

I'm using the following:

```
keepFirst[lst_List] := Module[{u = Unique[], t},
  t = Flatten[PadRight[lst, Automatic, u], {{2}, {1}}];
  t = Block[{f}, f[a_] := (f[a] = u; a); Map[f, #]] & /@ t;
  DeleteCases[Flatten[t, {{2}, {1}}], u, {2}]];
```

Does what I need, reasonably quick, wondering if there's perhaps a cleaner/more efficient means.

(*N.b*: Above fn is output from a function I use to generate these for differing dimensions/etc. - in the 2D case, `Flatten[...,{{2},{1}}]` can obviously simplify to the slightly faster `Transpose@...` with minor speed increase.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another solution using memoization:

```
keepFirst[lst_List] := Module[{isFirst},
  isFirst[elem_, col_] := (isFirst[elem, col] = False; True);
  Pick[lst, MapIndexed[isFirst[#1, Last[#2]] &, lst, {2}]]
  ]
```

Comment: Nice idea- slightly slower in my tests using `RandomInteger[100000, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 100000]`. +1

Comment: Accepted, fits the "cleaner" part of the OP, quite elegant...

Answer (score 10):

This is faster for the given array:

```
keepFirstK7[lst_List] := 
 Delete[lst, 
  Flatten[(GatherBy[Position[lst, #], Last] & /@ 
      DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@lst])[[All, All, 2 ;;]], 2]]

keepFirstK7@rArray
```

$\ $ `{{4, 2, 1, 0}, {2}, {0, 0, 3, 3, 3}, {}, {3, 4}}`

---

Another approach

```
keepFirstK[lst_List] := Block[{sowFirst},
  sowFirst[int_, count_] := (sowFirst[int, count] = int; Sow[int]);
  Flatten /@ 
   Part[Reap[Block[{cnt = 1}, sowFirst[#, cnt++] & /@ #]] & /@ lst, 
    All, 2]]
```

By using `Flatten[..., 1]` instead of `Flatten /@ ...` one would get rid of the empty lists.

---

Or simpler:

```
keepFirstN[lst_List] := Block[{nftn},
  nftn[int_, count_] := (nftn[int, count] = Nothing; int);
  Block[{cnt = 1}, nftn[#, cnt++] & /@ #] & /@ lst]
```

Comment: Try with `RandomInteger[100000, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 100000]`... much slower. +1 though.

Comment: @ciao I added another approach, that is faster for arrays like `RandomInteger[10, RandomInteger[1000]] &~Array~100000`

Comment: Mobile - will check on return...

Comment: I really like `keepFirstN`, even though it only works in V10.2 or later. But it can made simpler yet: `keepFirstN[lst_List] := Block[{nftn},  nftn[val_, indx_] :=  (nftn[val, indx] = Nothing; val); MapIndexed[nftn[#1, #2] &, #] & /@ lst]`

Comment: @m_goldberg Your `keepFirstN` is more beautiful than mine, but unfortunately also slower.

Comment: No surprise that it is slower. `MapIndex` is known to be slow. I only brought it to your attention because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Uninspiring but thought I'd play:

```
func[lst_] := 
 Module[{res = Thread[{#, Range[Length@#]}] & /@ lst, f = Unique[]},
  (f[#] = 1) & /@ Flatten[res, 1];
  Cases[#, {x_, 1} :> x] & /@ Map[{#[[1]], f[#]++} &, res, {2}]]
```

so `func[rArray]`

yields:

> {{4, 2, 1, 0}, {2}, {0, 0, 3, 3, 3}, {}, {3, 4}}

Comment: +1, but slower in my tests , e.g. with list `RandomInteger[100000, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 100000]`

Comment: @ciao never been good efficiency...just wanted to play :)

Answer (score 2):

sakra made good use of [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html), but [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) is superfluous if we use [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) directly, as done in the first method in [Delete duplicate elements from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/delete-duplicate-elements-from-a-list/2423#2423)

```
coldupe[lst_List] :=
  Module[{f},
    mem : f[elem_, _] := (mem = Sequence[]; elem);
    MapIndexed[f[#, Last[#2]] &, lst, {2}]
  ]

coldupe[rArray]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 1, 0}, {2}, {0, 0, 3, 3, 3}, {}, {3, 4}}
> ```

And now I see that m_goldberg posted basically this [in a comment two years ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91191/faster-position-based-duplicate-removal-in-a-ragged-array#comment247988_91245).

Comment: What's up, Rip Van Winkle? ;=) and +1...

Answer (score 1):

If one has some prior knowledge about the shape (`maxL`) and values (`nVal`) of the possible arrays, a compiled function can be used.

```
maxL = Max[Length /@ rArray]
nVal = Max@Flatten[rArray] + 1

keepFirstKC = 
 With[{hA = ConstantArray[0, {nVal + 1, maxL}], nothing = nVal + 1}, 
  Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 2}},
   Block[{testA = hA},
     Block[{cnt = 1}, 
        If[testA[[#, cnt]] == 0, testA[[#, cnt++]] = 1; #, 
           nothing] & /@ #] & /@ (lst + 1)] - 1, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ]]

keepFirstKF[lst_] := 
 DeleteCases[keepFirstKC@PadRight[lst, Automatic, nVal], nVal, {2}]
```

Depending on how speed is measured, using

```
deleteCases = With[{dc = nVal},
  Compile[{{intList, _Integer, 1}},
   DeleteCases[intList, dc], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
  ]

keepFirstKF[lst_] := 
 deleteCases /@ keepFirstKC[PadRight[lst, Automatic, nVal]]
```

can be faster.