# How to remove duplicate elements from two separated lists efficiently?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have two lists of elements:

```
indices = {Prime /@ Range[5000], Prime /@ Range[100, 300]} // Flatten;
values = RandomReal[100, 3] & /@ Range[Length[indices]];
```

where the i-th element in `indices` corresponds to the i-th element in `values`.

Now I want to remove the duplicates in `indices` as well as their corresponding elements in `values`.

I do it in this way:

```
removeDuplicates[indices_, values_] := Block[{t}, 
    t = Thread[{indices, values}];
    DeleteDuplicates[t, First[#1] == First[#2] &] // Transpose
];
```

However, it takes a long time to run:

```
removeDuplicates[indices, values]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {9.7083, Null} *)
```

If I only remove elements in `indices`, it is actually quite fast:

```
DeleteDuplicates[indices]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.000545, Null} *)
```

Is there a simple way to remove pairing duplicates efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DeleteDuplicates[t, First[#1] == First[#2] &` needs to compare every element with every other - that's O(n^2) comparisons, that's why it's so much slower. If you have a recent version of MMA, you can simply use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html): (e.g. `DeleteDuplicatesBy[t, First]`) instead.

If you have an older version of MMA, you could use associations to map from modifies index-sets to value-sets quickls:

```
mapping = Association[Thread[indices -> values]];
uniqueIndices = DeleteDuplicates[indices];
{uniqueIndices, mapping /@ uniqueIndices}
```

**ADD**: As @Chris pointed out, `Association` is relatively new, too. Another way would be using `GatherBy`:

```
Transpose[GatherBy[Transpose[{indices, values}], First][[All, 1]]]
```

Comment: +1 However, associations also only appeared in version 10.

Comment: Thank you. `Transpose[GatherBy[Transpose[{indices, values}], First][[All, 1]]]` runs pretty much faster than `DeleteDuplicatesBy[t, First]`.

Answer (score 4):

**Proposition**

Just for fun, here is a version inspired by the `DeleteDuplicates` code of Mr.Wizard in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2423/31159),

```
deleteDuplicates[list1_, list2_] := Module[{f, i = 0, bag = Internal`Bag[{}]},
    f[y_] := (i++; f[y] := (Internal`StuffBag[bag, {++i}]; Nothing); y);
    {f /@ list1, Delete[list2, Internal`BagPart[bag, All]]}]
```

For *Mathematica* versions older than 10.2, `Nothing` can be replaced by `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`.

**Timings**

This code is much faster than OP's but is slower than the best solutions by a factor of roughly 3. Considering OP's data

```
indices = {Prime /@ Range[5000], Prime /@ Range[100, 300]} // Flatten;
values = RandomReal[100, 3] & /@ Range[Length[indices]];
```

and gathering the solutions posted so far

```
nikie1[list1_, list2_] := Module[{uniqueIndices = DeleteDuplicates[list1]},
   {uniqueIndices, Association[Thread[indices -> values]] /@ uniqueIndices}];

nikie2[list1_, list2_] := Transpose[
    GatherBy[Transpose[{list1, list2}], First][[All, 1]]];

chris1[list1_, list2_] := Module[{data = MapThread[List, {list1, list2}]}, 
   Part[data, Sort[Part[Range[Length@data][[#]], 
     Most@FoldList[Plus, 1, Length /@ Split[data[[All, 1]][[#]]]]]]] &@
       Ordering[First /@ data] // Transpose];

chris2[list1_, list2_] := 
   Transpose[DeleteDuplicatesBy[MapThread[List, {list1, list2}], First]];

xavier[list1_, list2_] := Module[{f, i = 0, bag = Internal`Bag[{}]},
   f[y_] := (i++; f[y] := (Internal`StuffBag[bag, {++i}]; Nothing); y);
   {f /@ list1, Delete[list2, Internal`BagPart[bag, All]]}]
```

I get the following timings on my computer

```
timings = Through[Map[Composition[AbsoluteTiming, #] &, 
  {nikie1, nikie2, chris1, chris2, xavier}][indices, values]][[All, 1]];

TableForm[Transpose[{{nikie1, nikie2, chris1, chris2, xavier}, timings}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice comparison. It seems that `nikie2` is the fastest and most simple way to achieve this goal.

Comment: +1.  I would just add, an advantage of the more low level methods (like DD2) is that they're more open to modification for adding new functionality which may not be provided by the higher-level methods.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from a method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35214/363), this will work on older versions.

```
DD2[data_] := Part[data,
    Sort[Part[
      Range[Length@data][[#]],
      Most@FoldList[Plus, 1, Length /@ Split[data[[All, 1]][[#]]]]
      ]]
    ] &@Ordering[First /@ data]

data = MapThread[List, {indices, values}]

ans = Transpose[DD2[data]]
```

**Why different answers?**

Actually I would have expected the answer from DD2, but *which* duplicate wasn't specified.

```
indices = {1163, 919, 1163, 919};
values = {
   {41.71, 31.16, 34.19},
   {60.68, 23.29, 87.79},
   {0.22, 58.81, 76.78},
   {0.76, 94.68, 19.81}};

mapping = Association[Thread[indices -> values]];
uniqueIndices = DeleteDuplicates[indices];
{uniqueIndices, mapping /@ uniqueIndices}
```

> {{1163, 919}, {{0.22, 58.81, 76.78}, {0.76, 94.68, 19.81}}}

The association is picking up the last match associated with a duplicate.

All the following solutions arrive at the same answer.

```
data = MapThread[List, {indices, values}];
Transpose[DD2[data]]
```

> {{1163, 919}, {{41.71, 31.16, 34.19}, {60.68, 23.29, 87.79}}}

```
Transpose[DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, First]]
```

> {{1163, 919}, {{41.71, 31.16, 34.19}, {60.68, 23.29, 87.79}}}

```
Transpose[GatherBy[Transpose[{indices, values}], First][[All, 1]]]
```

> {{1163, 919}, {{41.71, 31.16, 34.19}, {60.68, 23.29, 87.79}}}

Comment: The results are different from DeleteDuplicatesBy[t, First].

Comment: I find they match.  Please see my edit.  The same applies for the full dataset.

Comment: Yes, they match. Sorry about the mistake.