# How to remove repeated permutations?

Tags: permutation

I want to get the Permutations on the elements of a list. Then I'm doing this:

```
a = Drop[Permutations[Range[1, 16], 2], {1, 17}]
i = 15;
While[i <= (240 - 16), a = Drop[a, {i, i}]; i = (i + (16 - 1))]
```

The first line of the code gives me all the permutations, but I do not want repetitions, like: I already have `{1,2}`, I do not want the `{2,1}`.

I'm trying to do this way but there's no result yet.

Any help?

Comment: I am still confused about how what you want differs from `Subsets[list, {2}]`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(44)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44/121),
[(1302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/121)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did I understand correctly?

```
Subsets[Range[1, 16], {2}]
```

EDIT: If you want to use `Permutations`, you could use

```
DeleteDuplicates[Permutations[Range[16], {2}], Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &]
```

which deletes all "duplicates", where "duplicate" is defined by the equality of the two lists when sorted (ie, `{2,3}` is "equal" to `{3,2}` for purposes of this comparison).

EDIT: The meaning of `#1` and `#2` may be demonstrated by this example:

```
f={#1,#2}&
```

and then `f[a,b]` evaluates to `{a,b}`. That is, you are defining a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) which takes two arguments, returning a list containing the two arguments, and assigning it to `f`. [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) could also be useful.

In the `DeleteDuplicates` example above, I am using as a test function (see second usage example in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) and also [this example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dqvzuhu05o-neboqu)) that considers two lists equal if they are the same after sorting; thus, `{3,4}` is equal to `{4,3}`, since when sorted they both become `{3,4}`.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272067/what-does-mean-in-mathematica).

Comment: What's the meaning of the #'s? I know # is a slot and it have something to do with patterns, but I never undertood how to use them. Any reference?

Comment: does this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html help?

Comment: It's the same of the Mathematica help. It's strange because there's a simple description on the slot thing, but it's always used on a bigger scope. Like.... With that information, i couldn't produce something like your code: DeleteDuplicates[Permutations[Range[16], {2}], Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &]

Comment: does my added explanation in the answer help? or the linked question? If not, try asking a more specific question

Answer (score 11):

You could try this as an alternative:

```
Sort /@ Permutations[Range@16, {2}] // Union
```

Comment: Union considers {1,2} = {2,1}, isn't it? I didn't remember of using basic math tools.

Comment: What's the function of `Sort/@`? I've looked at this page [link] (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html?q=Sort&lang=en) and i know it orders elements on a list but the elements of my list are already ordered and simply doing `Union@a` wont work, only `Sort /@ a // Union`

Comment: Union[{{2, 1}, {1, 2}}] returns {{2,1},{1,2}} so it seems for Union[] order is important. Perhaps not what you would expect.

Comment: The expression /@ maps the function Sort[] over all the values returned by the call to Permutations. The effect is to sort each permutation into numerical order. This makes {2,1} into {1,2} so that it matches {1,2} when Union[] is applied and the duplicates are then removed.

Comment: The Map function is fundamental to functional programming and a very useful tool to have at your disposal. It removes the need for loop counters etc that plague procedural programming and just applies any function to each element in a list. Functional programs often turn out to need a lot less code and avoid many of the bugs present in other styles of coding, particularly those associated with variables holding execution state which sometimes lose coherency. Hope that helps.

Comment: As you would like  {2,1} and {1,2} to be considered the same, i.e. order does not matter, technically what you want are combinations not permutations. Which is why some post processing is need on the output of Permutations.

Comment: @image_doctor The information provided in your comments could as well be written in the main answer. Actually, I think it _[should](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76/when-is-it-okay-to-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)_ be part of your answer!

Answer (score 9):

@acl showed the best way.  Because your list is defined as a `Range`, the particular solution for the case you gave is also found by

```
Table[{j, k}, {j, 15}, {k, j + 1, 16}]~Flatten~1
```

---

EDIT: Here's another way to solve it via `Permutations`:

```
Select[Permutations[Range@16, {2}], #[[2]] > #[[1]] &]
```

As TomD noted, this can be expressed alternatively as:

```
Select[Permutations[Range@16, {2}], OrderedQ]
```

Comment: Or, as a slight variation:  `Select[Permutations[Range@16, {2}], OrderedQ]`

Comment: @TomD Nice idea: OrderedQ as a selection criterion.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other approaches that have already been given, you can use `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Sort]`, which is new in 10.