# DeleteDuplicates Delete elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, matrix

I have a math problem about Mathematica, I am looking help from you.
I hope that you could help me.

The Math Problem:

```
list= { {0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,1,0} ,{1,2,3}};
```

as you know that list is a List,

and the first three elements of the list is list[[1]]、list[[2]]、list[[3]].

but the three elements of list[[1]]、list[[2]]、list[[3]] are all the same, that is 1,0,0.

the only difference is their order.

So I need a function to deal with the List:

The Results must been
`p={{0,0,1} ,{1,2,3}}`
(also can been p={{1,0,0} ,{1,2,3}},etc).

I know two functions can do that:

(1)

```
p = DeleteDuplicates [ list, Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] & ];
```

(2)

```
p = Union[list,  SameTest -> (SameQ[Sort[#1], Sort[#2]] &) ]
```

when List has 100,000 elements (Length[list]=100,000) , the speeds of these two functions

are too slow(It takes me a day, but has no results).

eg

```
list={};
For[i=1,i<=100000,i++,
list=Append[list,{0,0,Random[Integer,{1,5}]}]
];
p = DeleteDuplicates [ list, Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] & ];
```

Could you help me or give some suggestions ?

Comment: Can you not simply sort the subsets?: `DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ set]`

Comment: Related: [(3197)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3197), [(17041)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17041)

Comment: No,Can not, eg, list= { {0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,1,0} ,{3,2,1}};When I use sort the results is {{0,0,1},{1,2,3}},But I want that {3,2,1}'s elements order cannot change. (It is element's order in finite element, so cannot change order)

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate of one that I believe is equivalent.  Please take a look at it. (The link is now at the top of your question.)  The solution is to use `GatherBy` rather than `DeleteDuplicates` with a custom comparator, so you want: `First /@ GatherBy[set, Sort]`.  The reason why is explained in my answer there.

Comment: Ok,Thanks, I will look your questions carefully, Thanks!

Comment: The answer:list = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 40000, i++,
  list = Append[
    list, {Random[Integer, {1, 5}], Random[Integer, {1, 5}], 
     Random[Integer, {1, 5}]}]
  ];
First /@ GatherBy[list, Sort[#] &] // Timing // First
DeleteDuplicates[list, Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &] // Timing // First

Comment: By the way, try to get away from using `For` and `Append`.  Also, `Random` is deprecated; you should use `RandomInteger`, `RandomReal` etc.  This is not just syntax; they produce higher quality pseudorandom numbers.  Your `list` could be built with: `list = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {40000, 3}];`.  Faster, better, and a lot easier to write. :-)

Comment: More links for you: [(7924)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924), [(2930)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2930)

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard,I have another similar question to Consult.
list1 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {40000, 3}]; list2={1,2,3,4,5}; and I want to find that sublists of list1 that contain any element of list2? And I pastes the questions in the codes?The speed of the procedure is important.  Thanks for your help...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and the main problem is problaly that the speed of Intersection is slow

Comment: In your given example all subsets intersect because they only contain elements in the range {1, 5} which all belong to `list2`.  What does your actual data look like?  Also I think it would be better to post this (Question2) separately, along with the more realistic example data.  For *general* use I doubt `Intersection` can be greatly improved upon, however for certain data there are interesting options such as bit-masks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , I have pasted my problems again, Thanks for your help, It may some difficulty to understand all codes..But I have pointed that:list1=ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex;

list2=BoundaryPtsIndex;

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, and I have to say that the procedure may only work in Mathematica v10.0.0

Comment: YuYong, you should split this Question and post the second part as [a new Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,Ok,I did it http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55451/find-sublists-of-a-list-match-some-conditions