# Find sublists of a list that match some conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Question2::

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];

long = 100;
broad = 100;
height = 100;

pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {long, 0, 0}, {long, broad, 0}, {0, broad, 0},
   {0, 0, height}, {long, 0, height}, {long, broad, height}, {0, 
    broad, height}};
facets = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 5, 6, 2}}, {{2, 6, 7, 
     3}}, {{3, 7, 8, 4}}, {{4, 8, 5, 1}}};

inst = TetGenCreate[];
TetGenSetPoints[inst, pts];
TetGenSetFacets[inst, facets];

inst1 = TetGenTetrahedralize[inst, "pq1.414a4"];
ElemPtsCoord = TetGenGetPoints[inst1];
ElemFacesMadeofPtsIndex = TetGenGetFaces[inst1];
ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex = TetGenGetElements[inst1];

 Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[ElemPtsCoord, Polygon[ElemFacesMadeofPtsIndex]]]

ElemPtsCoordandIndex = ElemPtsCoord;
Do[PrependTo[ElemPtsCoordandIndex[[i]], i], {i, 1, 
   Length[ElemPtsCoordandIndex]}
  ];

ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex = ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex;
Do[PrependTo[ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex[[i]], i], {i, 1, 
   Length[ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex]}
  ];

BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex = GatherBy[ElemPtsCoordandIndex,
   (#1[[2]] == 0) || (#1[[2]] == 100) || (#1[[3]] == 0) || (#1[[3]] ==
        100) || (#1[[4]] == 0) || (#1[[4]] == 100) &];

BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex = If[
   BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1, 1]][[2]] == 0 ||
    BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1, 1]][[2]] == 100 ||
    BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1, 1]][[3]] == 0 ||
    BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1, 1]][[3]] == 100 ||
    BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1, 1]][[4]] == 0 ||
    BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1, 1]][[4]] == 100,

   BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[1]],
   BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex[[2]]];


BoundaryPtsIndex = 
  Flatten[Take[BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex, 
    Length[BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex], 1]];

ClassifiedElements = 
  GatherBy[ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex, 
   Intersection[BoundaryPtsIndex, Delete[#1, 1]] == {} &]
```

Introduction:

I have a cube sized 100*100*100. and I mesh it with fine mesh. So the total numbers of nodes and elements are huge.

and I have to find mesh tetrahedrons which are on the boundary.

First, Find points on the boundary faces-> "BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex".

Second, Find elements which has any point of "BoundaryPtsCoordandIndex".

This is my problem:

So the math problem is:

```
list1 = ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex;

list2 = BoundaryPtsIndex;
```

and Find all sublists of list1 that contain any element of list2 ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work pretty well.  Edit: now a bit faster.

```
rls = Thread[list2 -> True] // Dispatch;

Pick[list1, TrueQ /@ Or @@@ Replace[list1, rls, {2}]] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.546003, 75230}
> ```

On my system this takes just over half a second to find 75,230 boundary sets.

(I am running version 10.0.0 under Windows.)

---

Looking at Simon's answer I find the whole `killme` thing extraneous.  It is sufficient to merely replace all `list2` elements with one that does not appear in anywhere in `list1`.  I would instead write:

```
rls = Thread[list2 -> -1] // Dispatch;

Complement[list1, Replace[list1, rls, {2}]] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.327602, 75230}
> ```

For me this also tests faster than Simon's code, which takes:

> ```
> {0.374402, 75230}
> ```

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard, I am sorry to say what's the meaning of "/@ Or @@@", It seems that "TrueQ /@ Or @@@ Replace[list1, rls, {2}]" not equal to:   "TrueQ /@ Replace[list1, rls, {2}]" Or "TrueQ /@ Replace[list1, rls, {2}]". I know that /@(Map) and  @@@(Apply).

Comment: @YuYong `Or @@@` is to convert a list containing `True` to `True`:  `Or @@@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, True, 6}}` outputs `{1 || 2 || 3, True}`.  Then `TrueQ /@ converts anything not explicitly `True` to `False`:  `TrueQ /@ {1 || 2 || 3, True}` outputs `{False, True}`.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard,Yes, You are right. I think I have to Learn Mathematica's Functional Programming carefully. The speed of Conventional Programming is so slow. and I also have another similar questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55533/find-sublists-of-a-list-match-conditions-2...Can you help me again?

Comment: Ah, of course! I feel silly now :-)

Answer (score 1):

On my system this is  a little bit faster than Mr. Wizard's code, though it's a slightly odd way to approach the problem. I use a symbol which makes a list vanish when it appears as an element of that list...

```
killme /: {___, killme, ___} = Unevaluated[];

rls = Thread[list2 -> killme] // Dispatch;

result = Complement[list1, Replace[list1, rls, {2}]];
```

Comment: Yes, It seems so strange, because that the results of Replace[list1, rls, {2}] seems the same as list1 ... But the idea is great. and easy to understand. Cool!

Comment: Confirmed that this is a bit faster.  Let me see if I can beat it!