# Find sublists of a list match conditions (2)

Tags: list-manipulation

```
  Needs["TetGenLink`"];
    Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];

    long = 100;
    broad = 100;
    height = 100;

    pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {long, 0, 0}, {long, broad, 0}, {0, broad, 0},
       {0, 0, height}, {long, 0, height}, {long, broad, height}, {0, 
        broad, height}};
    facets = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 5, 6, 2}}, {{2, 6, 7, 
         3}}, {{3, 7, 8, 4}}, {{4, 8, 5, 1}}};

    inst = TetGenCreate[];
    TetGenSetPoints[inst, pts];
    TetGenSetFacets[inst, facets];

    inst1 = TetGenTetrahedralize[inst, "pq1.414a4"];
    ElemPtsCoord = TetGenGetPoints[inst1];
    ElemFacesMadeofPtsIndex = TetGenGetFaces[inst1];
    ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex = TetGenGetElements[inst1];

    Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[ElemPtsCoord, Polygon[ElemFacesMadeofPtsIndex]]]

    ElemPtsCoordandIndex = ElemPtsCoord;
    Do[PrependTo[ElemPtsCoordandIndex[[i]], i], {i, 1, 
       Length[ElemPtsCoordandIndex]}
      ];

    ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex = ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex;
    Do[PrependTo[ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex[[i]], i], {i, 1, 
       Length[ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex]}
      ];

   RetainElementsIndex=Range[1,Length[ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex]];

   ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord_, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex_, 
  Acen_, Bcen_, Ccen_, R1_, RetainElementsIndex_] := Module[
  {RetainElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIndex, ClassifiedElements, 
   ProjectedElementsIndex},

  RetainElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIndex = 
   ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex[[RetainElementsIndex]];

  ClassifiedElements = GatherBy[
    RetainElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIndex,
    Volume[
       RegionIntersection[
        Ball[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, R1],
        Simplex[
         ElemPtsCoord[[  Delete[#1, 1]  ]]
         ]
        ]
       ] != 0 &];

  ProjectedElementsIndex = If[
    Volume[
      RegionIntersection[
       Ball[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, R1],
       Simplex[
        ElemPtsCoord[[  Delete[ClassifiedElements[[1, 1]], 1]  ]]
        ]
       ]
      ] != 0,

    ClassifiedElements[[1]],

    ClassifiedElements[[2]]
    ];
  ProjectedElementsIndex = 
   Union[Flatten[
     Take[ProjectedElementsIndex, Length[ProjectedElementsIndex], 1]]];

  ProjectedElementsIndex

  ]


ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex, 
 62.84752406439229, 28.984094217780612, 72.55554474676572, 12.5, RetainElementsIndex]
```

Questions Background:

I have a cube sized 100*100*100, I have meshed it with fine meshes.
So the mesh elements set is `ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex`, The mesh points set is `ElemPtsCoord`.

And because `ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex` and `ElemPtsCoord` do not tell us elements(points)' oder.
So I add the points(elements) a order number to the first of the sublists:

ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex-> ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex

ElemPtsCoord-> ElemPtsCoordandIndex.

Math Problem:

A sphere(ball): the center is located at (Acen, Bcen, Ccen) and radius is R1).

and I want to find which elements belong(located in the ball or intersected with the ball) to the zone of the ball.

so the problem become to find sublists of list `ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndexandIdex`, which the volume of region which mesh tetrahedron and the ball intersected is not null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find sublists of a list that match some conditions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55451/find-sublists-of-a-list-that-match-some-conditions)

Comment: @ RunnyKine, No this is another questions. and I have not finished it yet, another question

Comment: Okay, next time finish your questions before posting. It looked like a duplicate initially.

Comment: @ RunnyKine Thanks,I am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CountTrue[list_] := Module[
       {},
       Count[list, True] >= 1
       ];

    ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord_, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex_, Acen_, 
       Bcen_, Ccen_, R1_, RetainElementsIndex_] := Module[
       {RELPtsIndex, temp1, temp2},

       RELPtsIndex = ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex[[RetainElementsIndex]];

       temp1 = 
        Reap[Do[Sow[  ElemPtsCoord[[RELPtsIndex[[i]]  ]] ], {i, 1, 
            Length[RELPtsIndex]} ] ][[2, 1]];
       temp2 = Table[Table[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, {4}], {Length[temp1]}];

       Flatten[
        Position[
         Map[
          CountTrue,
          Negative[
           Map[Norm, temp1 - temp2, {2}] - 
            Table[Table[R1, {4}], {Length[temp1 - temp2]}]
           ]
          ],
         True]
        ]

       ];

Length[ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex, 40, 
   40, 40, 10, RetainElementsIndex]] // Timing
```

Comment: This answer need to be optimistic