# A code deal with Lists operation ---Needs optimizion

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review

I have written some code to deal with lists, But the speed of the code is slow, Could Someone help me to speed up it?

Probably could rewrite it with Functional Programming!

Give me some ideas!

The whole code is located on

[Find sublists of a list match conditions (2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55533/find-sublists-of-a-list-match-conditions-2/55543#55543)

```
CountTrue[list_] := Module[
           {},
           Count[list, True] >= 1
           ];

        ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord_, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex_, Acen_, 
           Bcen_, Ccen_, R1_, RetainElementsIndex_] := Module[
           {RELPtsIndex, temp1, temp2},

           RELPtsIndex = ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex[[RetainElementsIndex]];

           temp1 = 
            Reap[Do[Sow[  ElemPtsCoord[[RELPtsIndex[[i]]  ]] ], {i, 1, 
                Length[RELPtsIndex]} ] ][[2, 1]];
           temp2 = Table[Table[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, {4}], {Length[temp1]}];

           Flatten[
            Position[
             Map[
              CountTrue,
              Negative[
               Map[Norm, temp1 - temp2, {2}] - 
                Table[Table[R1, {4}], {Length[temp1 - temp2]}]
               ]
              ],
             True]
            ]

           ];

    Length[ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex, 40, 
       40, 40, 10, RetainElementsIndex]] // Timing
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my heart is not in this kind of problem right now.  Hopefully someone else feels more inclined to help.  I retagged the question as seemed appropriate.

Comment: I ate something and it put me in a better mood.  Please see my answer below.  I only refined the code presented; I did not attempt to refine the algorithm itself or reimagine the solution.

Answer (score 3):

#### Regarding `CountTrue`:

1. There is generally no need for the empty `Module`.  You can use [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) if you need several operations in sequence.  Here even that is not necessary.
2. There is no need to count all appearances of `True` in an expression to determine if one is present: instead use [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html).

That gives us:

```
CountTrue[list_] := MemberQ[list, True]
```

#### Regarding the main function:

Regarding the line:

```
temp1 = 
  Reap[Do[Sow[ElemPtsCoord[[RELPtsIndex[[i]]]]], {i, 1, Length[RELPtsIndex]}]][[2, 1]]
```

1. `Sow` and `Reap` are not needed here; a simple `Table` would suffice.
2. Rather than a numeric iterator i from 1 to `Length[RELPtsIndex]` you could use:

   ```
   Table[ElemPtsCoord[[i]], {i, RELPtsIndex}]
   ```
3. Even that is overkill as a `Map` will do:

   ```
   ElemPtsCoord[[#]] & /@ RELPtsIndex
   ```

Regarding the line:

```
temp2 = Table[Table[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, {4}], {Length[temp1]}];
```

1. You do not need to nest `Table` commands; there is a compound syntax:

   ```
   Table[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, {Length[temp1]}, {4}]
   ```

Regarding the line(s):

```
Flatten[Position[
  Map[CountTrue, 
   Negative[Map[Norm, temp1 - temp2, {2}] - 
     Table[Table[R1, {4}], {Length[temp1 - temp2]}]]], True]]
```

1. `Length[temp1 - temp2]` is strange; a subtraction is carried out on the arrays but the result is simply equivalent to `Length[temp1]`
2. `Table[Table[ . . .` could again be replaced with one `Table`, but:
3. The entire `Table` (or `ConstantArray`) output is simply taking the place of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) attribute, which the operator already has.  Use instead:

   ```
   Map[Norm, temp1 - temp2, {2}] - R1
   ```
4. `Negative`, `CountTrue`, `Position` and `Flatten` can all be replaced with:

   ```
   SparseArray[UnitStep[a] ~Total~ {2}, Automatic, 4]["AdjacencyLists"]
   ```

   Where `a` represents the output from (3) above.

#### Rolling all of this into one:

```
ProjectedElemsIndex[
 ElemPtsCoord_,
 ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex_,
 Acen_, Bcen_, Ccen_, R1_,
 RetainElementsIndex_
] :=
 Module[{RELPtsIndex, temp1, temp2, a},
   RELPtsIndex = ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex[[RetainElementsIndex]];
   temp1 = ElemPtsCoord[[#]] & /@ RELPtsIndex;
   temp2 = Table[{Acen, Bcen, Ccen}, {Length[temp1]}, {4}];
   a = Map[Norm, temp1 - temp2, {2}] - R1;
   SparseArray[UnitStep[a] ~Total~ {2}, Automatic, 4]["AdjacencyLists"]
 ];
```

Timing:

```
ProjectedElemsIndex[ElemPtsCoord, ElemElemsMadeofPtsIndex, 40, 40, 40, 10, 
   RetainElementsIndex] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.327602, 2797}
> ```

Your original code yields:

> ```
> {2.262014, 2797}
> ```

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard,Yes, Your answer is very quick and cool, thanks for your help these days. and now I realize how powerful Mathematica it is, and so many things I need to learn. A good code design will save me so many time. Thanks!

Comment: I want to know what you ate to change your mood. I could use a little something that would excite my interest in some of the current crop of questions. As long as it not an illegal substance, of course :-)

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm afraid my strange eating habits will help no one, but since you asked: corn chips and salsa, summer squash, and chocolate.  (Not all together.)  I'm having an artichoke next.  Bet you've never had *that* meal before. :o)

Comment: No, can't say I have. But it doesn't sound bad. I like all the individual ingredients you mentioned.

Comment: @m_goldberg You're right, it was not bad.  I guess the strange part is my eating it at 7:00AM. :^)

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard, Sir, I have another simple question, My other code use `Label` and `Goto`, Is there any other function to realize the same function and the speed is quick?

Comment: @user18688 I would need to see the code to answer that properly.  Go ahead and post a new question.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard, The code is used to deal with my research, It continues previous codes, But its background my a little difficult to understand, I will edit my code in English, and will paste it somewhere on the web! Thank you.