# DeleteDuplicate from a list with {x == y, y == x} -> {x == y};

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I tell Mathematica that it should delete equal elements from a list, which aren't in the same order. For example

```
list={x == y, y == x} ;
```

should become `{x == y`.

Comment: This answer is the answer: [How to remove repeated permutations?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55251/5478)

Comment: You can also use `Reduce[list]` but for more complex cases you can get reductions which are not expected.

Comment: Union[Simplify[list]] seems to work for lists of equalities

Comment: Also duplicates:  [(44)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44/121), 
[(1302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/121)