# Faster Alternative to DeleteDuplicates for deleting elements in list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list in this style

```
data={{a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1}, {a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2}}
```

I need to delete all elements in which `b1` is equal to `b2` and so on. I only have to test b. The list I use have more than 15000 elements. I used `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[data, {_, #1, _, _, _, _} == {_, #2, _, _, _, _} &]
```

I know this method gives a correct result because I tested it on a small amount of data.

But in a list with more than 15,000 elements after 20 minutes of running without success. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: Have you searched the forum? There are some threads about his, for instance here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35214/187

Comment: @halirutan Nope, I didn't ;-D.  Was too excited that I knew a v10 function.

Comment: Haha...I am realy not againt leraning so can you explain me one of these faster methodes in the thread you mentioned? Like I am a real beginner....:)

Answer (score 7):

Similar to [Mr.Wizard's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-to-use-union-on-list-of-lists-without-sorting-them-first/540#540)**, we can use `GatherBy`

```
GatherBy[data, #[[2]] &][[All, 1]]
```

I must say I was surprised* how much faster than `DeleteDuplicatesBy` this is:

```
data = RandomInteger[1000, {15000, 5}];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Part[#, 2] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
GatherBy[data, #[[2]] &][[All, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {12.071266, Null}
  {0.004069, Null}
*)
```

With fewer duplicates:

```
data = RandomInteger[10000, {15000, 5}];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Part[#, 2] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
GatherBy[data, #[[2]] &][[All, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {62.941921, Null}
  {0.017356, Null}
*)
```

*That's because I forgot about this: [DeleteDuplicatesBy is not performing as I'd hoped. Am I missing something?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/deleteduplicatesby-is-not-performing-as-id-hoped-am-i-missing-something).

**And it turns out [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) answer to the question in the previous note * is also almost the same as this one.

Comment: @RunnyKine It figures such a solution is already on the site.  (And thanks!)

Comment: Thank you tested the method of @MichaelE2 and it works like a charm...can you explain the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

In version 10 we have `DeleteDuplicatesBy` which seems to be much faster:

```
t = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10^3, 5}];
DeleteDuplicates[t, 
   {_, #1, _, _, _, _} == {_, #2, _, _, _, _} &]; // AbsoluteTiming
DeleteDuplicatesBy[t, Part[#, 2] &] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.488, 0.001 *)
```

Comment: FYI, you mention c1/c2 in the text but appear to use b1/b2 in your example.

Comment: Okay I still use mathematica 9...I have to wait that school s begin again so I can get the 10....@ halirutan I saw other threads but I already have problems understanding what the & at the end is for so undertanding other exemples without explications is a bit hard :) :)